# How to create a class with get and set methods?

Tags: python, class, methods, properties

I want to create a class myCalc that has a constructor, with get and set methods and uses a property. I understand the get and set methods but am having trouble with putting all of the pieces together so it performs what I want it to do. What I have so far is this:

```
class myCalc(object):

    def __init__(self):
            self._ =name

        def (self):
            """Get the answer doubled."""
            return self._plus

        def (self):
            """Get the answer squared."""
            return self._times
```

I'd like to get as far as having the program respond with properties that double and square the number in the object. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What is it that you want to get and set? Particularly set. I don't see much call for a setter here.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters

Answer (score 6):

A property object has getter, setter, and deleter methods
You should use decorators as follows:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

If you want it readonly, just use @property and remove the two others

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Appreciate the answers so far. The reason why I want a get and set method is to retrieve and set the value of a property named “name,” that reflects the object’s name.

Answer (score 1):

A simple object that has `doubled` and `squared` properties

```
class myCalc(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    def dbler(self):
        return self.value*2
    doubled = property(dbler)
    squared = property(lambda self: self.value**2)
    # equivalent with the decorator
    @property
    def cubed(self):
        return self.value**3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = myCalc(10)
    print x # 10
    print x.doubled  # 20
    print x.squared  # 100
    print x.cubed # 1000
```

Adapted from http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties

Comment: If I wanted to adapt this to allow a user to change the name by using the get and set properties, would it need the raw input code to refer back to the get/set?

Answer (score 0):

class myCalc(object):

```
def_init_(self, value)
self.value=value

def_init_(self, name)
print "Welcome to myCalc!"

self._name=name

def get_name(self):
        return self._name

def set_name(self, new_name):
    if new_name=="":
        print "You mut enter a name."
    else:
        self._name=new_name
        print "The name has been changed."

def_str_(self)
return str(self.value)

def dbler(self):
    return self.value*2

doubled=property(dbler)
squared=property(lambda self: self.value**2)

name=property(get_name, set_name)

def talk(self):
    print "\nWelcome, this is," self.name
```

if *name*=='*main*':
    x= myCalc(5)
    print x
    print x.doubled
    print x.squared

mainline

calc=myMath("Calculator")
calc.talk()

print "\nmyCalc's name is:",
print calc.name

print "\nChanging myCalc's name."
calc.name=""

calc.talk()

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit."

Here is what I am looking to do, however I keep coming across errors. I want to be able to change the object name AND number.