# In Python, how do I reference a variable that was defined in a function object from outside that function object?

Tags: python, function, variables, object

I want to be able to get variables such as dns_float_a that were defined inside the latitude() function object to work outside latitude().

The section of code I'm working with is below. It shows two variable objects defined using *def ():*. I then want to print the equation at the bottom, but in order to do this I need to reference the variables within the function objects.

PS this is literally the first program I've ever written (it's part of a longer latitude/longitude conversion program) so try don't assume I know much please!

Thanks in advance!

```
def latitude():
    #LATITUDE
    print "***Degrees/Minutes/Seconds >>> Decimal Degrees***"
    print
    print "Input Latitude"

    dns_a=raw_input("Degrees: ")
    mns_a=raw_input("Minutes: ")
    sns_a=raw_input("Seconds: ")
    ns=raw_input("North (1) or South (2): ")

    dns_float_a=float(dns_a)
    mns_float_a=float(mns_a)
    sns_float_a=float(sns_a)
    ns_float=float(ns)

    #south
    if ns_float==2:
        dns_float_a=dns_float_a*(-1)
        mns_float_a=mns_float_a*(-1)
        sns_float_a=sns_float_a*(-1)
        ns_x="South"

    #north
    elif ns_float==1:
        dns_float_a=dns_float_a*1
        mns_float_a=mns_float_a*1
        sns_float_a=sns_float_a*1
        ns_x="North"

    elif ns_float<1 or ns_float>2 or ns_float>1 and ns_float<2:
        print
        print "*Invalid Input*"
        latitude()

def longitude():
    #LONGITUDE
    print
    print "Input Longitude"

    dns_b=raw_input("Degrees: ")
    mns_b=raw_input("Minutes: ")
    sns_b=raw_input("Seconds: ")
    ns=raw_input("East (1) or West (2): ")

    dns_float_b=float(dns_b)
    mns_float_b=float(mns_b)
    sns_float_b=float(sns_b)
    ns_float=float(ns)

    #south
    if ns_float==2:
        dns_float_b=dns_float_b*(-1)
        mns_float_b=mns_float_b*(-1)
        sns_float_b=sns_float_b*(-1)
        ns_x="South"

    #north
    elif ns_float==1:
        dns_float_b=dns_float_b*1
        mns_float_b=mns_float_b*1
        sns_float_b=sns_float_b*1
        ns_x="North"

    elif ns_float<1 or ns_float>2 or ns_float>1 and ns_float<2:
        print
        print "*Invalid Input*"
        longitude()

latitude()
longitude()

#(d/m/s)ns_float_a
decimal_degrees_latitude=(dns_float_a)+(mns_float_a/60)+(sns_float_a/3600)
#(d/m/s)ns_float_b
decimal_degrees_longitude=(dns_float_b)+(mns_float_b/60)+(sns_float_b/3600)

print
print "Results:"
print
print "Latitude: ", decimal_degrees_latitude
print "Longitude: ", decimal_degrees_longitude
print
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. Look [here][1] for the solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-in-python-without-using-global

Comment: @cleros: I don't think it's a duplicate...or is at least different enough from that other question to warrant not being closed. BTW, to put an inline link in a comment use something like `[Google](http://www.google.com/)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) inside Python.  Basically, you can not access variables defined inside of a function outside of the function.

One way to get around this is to pass the variables you need as a return type from the function.  This actually can simplify your code since you do not need to have _a and _b for all variables in each function.  The scoping rules mean that you can have a variable of the same name in two different functions and they do not override each-other.  Add the following line at the end of the latitude and longitude functions:

```
return dns_float,mns_float,sns_float
```

Then change the function calls to:

```
dns_float_a,mns_float_a,sns_float_a = latitude()
dns_float_b,mns_float_b,sns_float_b = latitude()
```

Alternatively, you could move the latitude and longitude calculations into the functions themselves.  Change the last line of each function to:

```
return dns_float+mns_float/60+sns_float/3600
```

Then change the function calls to:

```
decimal_degrees_latitude = latitude()
decimal_degrees_longitude = longitude()
```

Comment: In my (and many other folks) option, this approach is better than having functions reference variables in other functions or having them all access (and possibly change) global variables.

Answer (score 2):

return values from a function, writing at the end:

```
return dns_float_a, mns_float_a, sns_float_a
```

and use outside:

```
dns, mns, sns = latitude()
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have been told how to make data from inside the function available outside.

But you can do even more: as the two functions are nearly identical, you could combine most of them into one generic one.

```
    class InvalidInputError(ValueError): pass

    def enter_degrees(input_what, pos_string, neg_string):
        print
        print "Input " + input_what
        d_a = int(raw_input("Degrees: "))
        m_a = int(raw_input("Minutes: "))
        s_a = int(raw_input("Seconds: "))
        dir = int(raw_input(pos_string + " (1) or " + neg_string + " (2)"))

        # south or west - negative:
        if dir == 2:
            d_a = -d_a
            m_a = -m_a
            s_a = -s_a
            dir_x = neg_string

        # north or east - positive
        elif ns_float==1:
            dir_x = pos_string
        else:
            raise InvalidInputError("1 or 2!")
        # return d_a, m_a, s_a, dir_x
        return d_a + m_a / 60.0 + s_a / 3600.0

    def enter_degrees_loop(input_what, pos_string, neg_string):
        while True:
            try:
                return enter_degrees(input_what, pos_string, neg_string)
            except InvalidInputError, e:
                print e # output the error
                continue

    def enter_latitude():
        return enter_degrees_loop("Latitude", "North", "South")

    def enter_longitude():
        return enter_degrees_loop("Longitude", "East", "West")

    print "***Degrees/Minutes/Seconds >>> Decimal Degrees***"
    print

    latitude = enter_latitude()
    longitude = enter_longitude()

    print
    print "Results:"
    print
    print "Latitude: ", latitude
    print "Longitude: ", longitude
    print
```

As you can see, I have made some additional changes:

- I changed the conversion from `float()` to `int()`: it makes no sense to have have non-integers here
- I have put the `print` statements where they belong
- I use an exception to indicate input error and wrap another layer around that all to loop until all was entered correctly
- I replace `d_a * (-1)` with `-d_a` and `d_a * 1` with a mere `d_a`
- I move the calculation into the innermost function

What still can be done:

- Check the degrees, minutes and seconds for correct range
- Omit what is not needed (e. g. `dir_x`)