# How to call keys from a dictionary which is inside a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key

I have the following code:

```
def all_dsc(x):
    dict={'a':x+2,'b':x-2}
    return dict
```

I would like to to call keys from specifically this dictionary outside of the function.
smthn like:

```
all_dsc.dict.keys()
```

What's the best way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a function variable outside the function in Python without using \`global\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-in-python-without-using-global)

Comment: @Lav: that's not actually all that helpful a duplicate. Setting an attribute on the function is no different from setting a global; all you did is namespace it, but many issues with globals still apply (it is not thread-safe, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access locals in a function from outside the function. All you can do is return the dictionary object by *calling* the function, which you already do.

Call the function, and then just treat the result of the call expression as a dictionary:

```
all_dsc(42).keys()
```

Demo:

```
>>> all_dsc(42)
{'a': 44, 'b': 40}
>>> all_dsc(42).keys()
['a', 'b']
```

Note that you really shouldn't use the name of a built-in type as a variable if you can avoid it. `dict` is a built-in type, so try to use a different name here:

```
def all_dsc(x):
    mapping = {'a': x + 2, 'b': x - 2}
    return mapping
```

or even avoid creating a local at all, since it doesn't matter here:

```
def all_dsc(x):
    return {'a': x + 2, 'b': x - 2}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, didnt know that I have to pass an argument to the function to call the keys.

Comment: another question: what if i have multiple dictionaries in a function? how do i call the keys from each of them?

Comment: @MarioL: return them all in a tuple: `return d1, d2, d3`, then index the tuple or use tuple unpacking to store the dictionaries in separate variables first.