# Is it possible to access a local variable in another function?

Tags: python

Goal: Need to use local variable in another function. Is that possible in Python?

I would like to use the local variable in some other function. Because in my case I need to use a counter to see the number of connections happening and number of connections releasing/ For that I am maintaining a counter. To implement that I have written sample code for count and returning local variable in another function.

How can I print `t` & `my_reply` in the `test()` function?

Code: counter_glob.py

```
my_test = 0
t = 0

def test():
    print("I: ",t)
    print("IIIIIIII: ",my_reply)

def my():
    global t
    reply = foo()
    t = reply
    print("reply:",reply)
    print("ttttt:",t)

def foo():
    global my_test
    my_test1 = 0
    my_test += 1
    print my_test1
    my_test1 = my_test
    my_test += 1
    print("my_test:",my_test1)
    return my_test1

my()
```

Result:

```
> $ python counter_glob.py
 0
 ('my_test:', 1)
 ('reply:', 1)
 ('ttttt:', 1)
```

Comment: No you can't, that's what "local" means. Besides that, you don't define a variable of any kind named `my_reply` anywhere in your code.

Comment: in the sample code , I have a my function , in my function I am assigning reply to global variable . When I print global variable in my function i.e t . Printing value as expected . but I am not sure why in test function its not printing ? because t is updated with reply in my function.

Comment: In the function `my()`, you assign a value to a local variable named `reply` and then assign that to a global variable named `t`. In the `test()` function you reference `t`, the global variable, and another named `my_reply`, which has not been defined anywhere. `my_reply` is not another name for the local variable `reply` in the other function. You can't do that. You could create a function attribute in `my()` and access it in `test()` using the technique shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19327712/355230) to another question. This would allow you to define a `my.reply`.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to access the local scope of a function. You can return the whole local scope if you want by calling `locals()` this will give you the entire local scope of a function, it's atypical to save the local scope. For your functions you can save the variables that you need in the function itself, *`func.var = value`*:

```
def test():
    print("I: ", my.t)
    print("IIIIIIII: ", my.reply)

def my():
    my.reply = foo() 
    my.t = m.reply
    print("reply:", my.reply)
    print("ttttt:", my.t)
```

You can now access `t` and `reply` normally. Each time you call your function `my`  and `reply` will be updated, whatever `foo` returns will be assigned to `my.reply`.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't get access to local variable outside function. But even you can in my opinion it will be a bad practice.

Why not use function or class.

```
connections = 0

def set_connection_number(value):
    global connections; connections = value;

def get_connection_number():
    global connections;
    return connections;

# test
set_connection_number(10)
print("Current connections {}".format(get_connection_number()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Except `closure` you wont have access to local vars outside the scope of your functions.
If variables have to be shared across different methods better make them as global as @pavnik has mentioned.