# Make variables declared in caller function available in the called function

Tags: python-3.x

I have two functions. They are not a part of any class. Just individual functions.
function `f1` calls `f2`. What I would like to do is print in `f2` the variables declared in `f1`.

How can I achieve this?

```
def f1():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    f2()

def f2():
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Comment: Take a look at http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

Comment: I think I did not explicitly state a few things in my question.
I know I can pass variables to f2() from f1(). I dont want to do that.

I am looking for a capability like :
`print <variable declared in caller function.`

Comment: Could you give me a convincing reason why you actually want to achieve this? :)

Comment: I have a case where f1() is a function that a fellow team member can write. For logging purposes, I will write a f2() function that will be called by f1(). My f2() function will refer back to f1() and save all variables.
That way I eliminate the possibility of the user writing the function f1() to miss out on any variable.

Comment: What you are trying now is not a very good practice. What would happen if your function changes... That would require a change of the other function in a lot of cases. By passing a list or array of variables it doesn't matter if it's empty, contains 2 or even more variables

Comment: It would also make sense to just pass one variable and call the log function twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
def f1():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    f2(locals())

def f2(dic):
    for key in dic:
        print(key, '=', dic[key])

f1()
```

`locals()` returns the the local variables and values in a dictionary.
Calling `f2` inside `f1` captures the locals of `f1` and is passed as
the argument `dic` for processing in `f2`.

Comment: Useful function indeed. Keep in mind that this will print all local variables, which in this case is what was asked of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the variables outside of the function first and then use the global modifier as in the second example. In this simple case however it would probably make more sense to just pass the variables to `f2()` (example 1).

You could also take a look at [Access a function variable outside the function without using `global`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global) if this is what you are looking for?

You generally also don't want to have code that checks what the caller function is as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global). **In any case your code must not be able to reach a state where `a` and `b` do not (yet) exist.**

**example 1**

```
def f1():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    f2(a, b)

def f2(a, b):
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

As stated in the comments this is not what you were looking for, so that's why you also have this possibility:

**example 2**

```
a=5
b=5

def f1():
    global a
    global b
    a = 10
    b = 20
    f2()

def f2():
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Calling `f1()` will print 10 and 20.