# Accessing the local variable outside of function - python

Tags: python, function, local-variables

```
In [1]: def test(array, func):
   ...:     midres = [x**2 for x in array]
   ...:     return func(midres)
   ...:

In [2]: test([1,2,3], sum)
Out[2]: 14

In [3]: p = test([2,3], sum)
```

Is it possible to get to the `midres` that was calculated when obtaining the value of `p` (i.e. `[4,9]` in this case), but without altering the `test` function? Of course, `p.midres` doesn't work; but is there a way to get it without including `midres` in the return statement?

I've seen [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global) but it doesn't really answer my question since I'd like to get to `midres` through `p`, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assign it to a variable outside the function? Why not return it?

Comment: @Li357 This requires a modification of `test`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this, and why do you want to do it without modifying `test`? The reason you want to do this will determine what the best answer would be, whether it's "just modify `test` already" or "here's a quick way to redefine `test` without retyping it" or "use a `func` that gives you access to `midres`" or "check out ipdb".

Comment: What if you redesign `test` so it doesn't have this variable? The internal workings of a function should be transparent to the callers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply decorate your test function, thus you do not have to change anything of test. And get exactly the attribute like `p.medris` as you wish.

```
def make_wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(array, f):
        def with_attribute():
            return func(array, f)
        with_attribute.midres = func(array, lambda x:x)
        return with_attribute
    return wrapped

@make_wrapper
def test(array, func):
    midres = [x**2 for x in array]
    return func(midres)

p=test([1,2,3],sum)

# if you want only the value
print(p()) # --> 14 

# if you want midres attribute 
print(p.midres) # --> [1, 4, 9]
```

If you want to make it looks a bit more uniform. You can create another attribute called, for example, value. Then you do not have to run the function `p()` to get its value.

```
def make_wrapper_value(func):
    def wrapped(array, f):
        def with_attribute():
            pass
        with_attribute.value = func(array, f)
        with_attribute.midres = func(array, lambda x:x)
        return with_attribute
    return wrapped

@make_wrapper_value
def test(array, func):
    midres = [x**2 for x in array]
    return func(midres)

p=test([1,2,3],sum)

print(p.value) # --> 14 
print(p.midres) # --> [1, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instrument the function `func` to return its parameter in addition to whatever it calculates:

```
def my_sum(x):
    return sum(x), x

p, midres = test([2,3], my_sum)
#13
#[4, 9]
```

Comment: Sure, but I was naively trying to see if there was a way to do it without changing the return statement. I guess another option would be to declare midres a global variable. Thanks!

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor that would not be a good option, and that would require you to modify the function anyway!

Comment: Note that I did not make any changes to `test`. Its `return` is exactly the same as before.