# How to use variables from a function in a different function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

This is my experimenting code:

```
def settingValues():
  hi = "Hello"
  name = "Jake"
  isTrue = True

def callingValues():
  print(hi, name, isTrue)

settingValues()
callingValues()
```

Obviously this emmits an error...
Is there an easy way to transfer the variables throughout the two functions?
**What I will be using this for requires setting quite a lot of variables... so I cant use 'global' for all of them.  :)**

Comment: You can pass the variables as arguments to `callingValues` like `callingValues(hi, name, isTrue)` and then use them like normal variables.

Comment: Wrap them in a class and use `self`?

Comment: Yes, you can, but this looks a lot like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a function variable outside the function without using \`global\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global)

Comment: Those aren't "def statements", those are functions. This might sound like a nitpick, but is conceptually important. You want to *pass values into functions as arguments* and *receive return values* from them. You don't want to think at the level of variable names or "transferring" them.

Answer (score 0):

Just use OOP:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hi = "Hello"
        self.name = "Jake"
        self.isTrue = True

    def callingValues(self):
        print(self.hi, self.name, self.isTrue)

sc = SomeClass()
sc.callingValues()
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way would be to define them as globals, which could then be accessed from all the functions in the same module

```
hi = ""
name = ""
isTrue = False
def settingValues():
    hi = "Hello"
    name = "Jake"
    isTrue = True

def callingValues():
   print(hi, name, isTrue)

settingValues()
callingValues()
```

Comment: Not only is this bad practice, it won't actually work.

Comment: To make variables global, you have to type the following code, not define them outside of a function.

`global hi, name, isTrue`