# AttributeError: type object 'lyssna' has no attribute 's'

Tags: python, class-attributes

I want to access one class attribute `s` and split it into 2 strings in another class. Any tips?

```
class lyssna:
    def du():
        s = '5-22'

class Fixish():

    strt, stpp = lyssna.s.split('-')
```

Comment: `lyssna` indeed doesn't have an attribute `s`, what makes you think it does? It has a method `du()` that defines a local variable called `s`, that's all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a function variable outside the function without using \`global\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global)

Comment: I see several potential discrepancies in your understanding of classes in general, and Python classes in particular.  I recommend that you work through a tutorial; there are many available on line.  I can't accurately suggest a way to "fix" your code, since it's not at a ll clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

`lyssna` is a class whose only (manually declared) attribute is `du`, a method. It's expected that `s` is not available from `lyssna` as `s` is a variable whose scope is restricted to `du`.

I don't know exactly why you want to define classes to do that job, because you can simply define a function as follows:

```
def split_hyphen(text):
    return text.split('-', maxsplit=1)
```

If the `text` of interest is an attribute of another class, you can access it using:

```
class A:
   text_of_intereset = '1-2'

split_hyphen(A.text_of_interest)
```

If it is an attribute of an instance of another class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, text_as_parameter):
        self.text_of_interest = text_as_parameter

# Create an instance of A
a = A('1-2')

split_hyphen(a.text_of_interest)
```