# How to call an action from def function - Python

Tags: python

I have python code as below

```
def call():
 input1 = input('Bot1:')
 input2 = input('Bot2:')
call()

input1
```

How to call 'input1' action only. I want after call it, the input1 action will start for inputting data on the screen.

But on above code... when I run, it show warning 'input1 not defined'

Thanks you!

Comment: Given this code, you can’t “call input1” from outside `input`.

Comment: Rename your `input()` function something else and call it with that new name.

Comment: @martineau how to do? Could you pls send me a example ?

Comment: Change `def input():` to `def something_else():`.

Comment: @martineau not correct . I have changed and call 'input1' but could not.

Comment: You have to call it using its new name — but leave the calls to `input()` _inside_ it alone.

Comment: @martineau pls check a post as above, I have modified.

Comment: You're getting the `input1 not defined` error because you are trying to access a variable that is local to the `call()` function. See [Access a function variable outside the function without using “global”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global).

Comment: @martineau sorry but I don't understand because i'm new with python. Could you pls suggest me example how to call sub action inside function from outside ??

Comment: I suppose you could add an argument to the `call()` function that told it which "action" to perform — but that alone won't allow you to access its `input1` local variable from outside the function. **Note** `input1` is a local _variable_, not an "action".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the local variables of a function from outside of it. One way to workaround that limitation would be to do something like this:

```
ACTION1, ACTION2 = 1, 2

def get_input(action):
    if action == ACTION1:
        return input('Bot1:')
    elif action == ACTION2:
        return input('Bot2:')
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Unknown action')

input1 = get_input(ACTION1)
```