# Access a list that is inside a function that is inside a class

Tags: python, class

Suppose that I have a class like this one in `a.py` file:

```
class MyClass():
    def get(self, request, format='json'):
        pipeline = ['something_here']
```

How can I access the list `pipeline` from another file like `b.py`?
`a.py` and `b.py` are in the same directory.

I'm trying something like this:

```
from a import MyClass

my_list = MyClass.pipeline
```

OBS.: I can't change the `a.py` file because other people are using it.

Comment: The list pipeline only exists during the method execution, before that its not created and after that its out of scope. If you need to access this list consider making it an attirbute of your class or class instance.

Comment: You can add `pipeline` as a function member, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global/19327712)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't change `a.py`, it is not possible to access this list. This list needs to be declared as a data member of `MyClass` or it needs to be returned from `MyClass.get()`. Otherwise, it is not possible

Comment: And how can I declare this list as a data member of `MyClass`?

Comment: Change it to `self.pipeline = ['something_here']`

Answer (score 3):

You can't access it directly. What you could do is either return it, receive it as an [attribute](https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide) of the instance, or make it a [global](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/) class variable.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this problem, is to use inheritance, and just change the logic for `MyClass` inside of a new class.

Given the following contents of `a.py`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def get(self, somestring):
        pipeline = [somestring]
        return pipeline
```

Creating a new object of `MyClass` and calling `get("somestring")`, will return a list containing just that string. However, we do not set the property inside of the class, so it's only available inside of the method itself.

Creating a new file, in this case `b.py`, we can create a new class, inheriting from the first class, and just modify the `get` method to have the logic we want.

```
from a import MyClass

class MyNewClass(MyClass):
    def get(self, somestring):
        self.pipeline = [somestring]
```

Inside of `b.py` we can then do the following test:

```
old = MyClass(1,2,3)
print(old.x, old.y, old.z)
print(old.get("this is the input-string"))

new = MyNewClass(4,5,6)
print(new.x, new.y, new.z)
new.get("This is the second input-string")
print(new.pipeline)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
['this is the input-string']
4 5 6
['This is the second input-string']
```