# calling a function within def() outside of it

Tags: python, list, function, numpy, user-defined-functions

How could I reach an element within a def function. I want to compute `mean` by using `p` which is inside of the def function.

```
import numpy as np 
k= np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
def func():
    p = k + 5
    l = k + 25
    
func()
mean = p + 10
```

Comment: lol? how about you return the variable in that function ?

Comment: There are other ways to [access a local variable from outside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global/19327712).

Comment: Please take some time to study basic Python before doing anything else like involving numpy or similar libraries.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
First, you need to learn to use the basic techniques of your current tools.  Work through a tutorial on functions; see how to transfer values into and out of the function.

Comment: @AndersonGreen you *definitely* shouldn't do that. That doesn't even actually access a local variable outside the function. It creates an attribute on an object which is being referred to by a global name. Which is just a confusing, round-about way of using mutable global state, a bad practice to begin with. Instead, the function *should* return the data that is required by the caller..

Answer (score 2):

When functions are done executing, all references to the variables within the function are cleared and removed from the stack. To get the values in the function, you have to use the `return` keyword.

Example:

```
def test_return_string():
    return "Hello World"

my_var = test_return_string()  # "Hello world" is returned and stored in my_var
print(my_var)  # Prints "Hello world"
```

When you do not define a `return` statement for the function. The function will return `None` by default.

Do note that returning a function will end its execution.

**TL;DR - To get the variable p, you would just have to `return p` at the end of the function.**

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
k= np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
def func(k):
    p = k + 5
    l = k + 25
    return(p,l)
    
p,l= func(k)
mean = p + 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
k= np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
def func(k):
    p = k + 5
    l = k + 25
    return p
    

mean = func(k) + 10
```

Here, I tried to make the more compact example with the less changes relative to your post.

When you def a function, in general you want to pass a variable through as argument to make the output related to the variable. So you `def func(variable):`, here `def func(k):`. That was the first "mistake".

Then, if you want the function to return a result, you need the `return` statement. That was the second "mistake".

Finally, if you want to use what the function returns, you need either to store the result in a variable, either to use it "in-place".

`func(k)` does not print (excepted in the python shell) nor assigns a value to a variable. It is just running and that's it.

`print(func(k))` shows the result in the terminal (for both script/python sheel), wheras `p = func(k)` assign what `func(k)` returns to variable `p`. Then you can use `p` to compute the mean as `mean = p + 10`. Or you can directly use `func(k)` instead, because it provides your mean calculation with the same value than `p` (cause `p = func(k)`)

Finally, in your function computing l seems to be useless now. So maybe think about removing it or using it within.

Comment: Can you give a brief explanation of what you did here? (I know it may seem obvious)

Comment: Hey! See my edit. If that is helpful, think about accepting the answer ;) (gray tick top left of my answer)

Comment: looks like this question is closed so OP can't. Your answer came up in my review queue and I voted to not delete it.

Comment: You're sure? I am pretty sure I got some answers accepted even after the question was closed (but new answers can't be posted). But I may be wrong. Anyway, not much a problem ;)