# I want to subtract one from "cd" variable every time the function activates. How can I do that?

Tags: python, function, loops, variables, math

```
def cdvalue():
    cd = cd - 1

def Cd():
    root.after(1000, cdvalue)
```

I want to subtract one from "cd" variable every time the function activates. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
def cdvalue():
    global cd
    cd = cd - 1

def Cd():
    root.after(1000, cdvalue)
```

If that's not what you want to achieve or you wanna use the fact that functions are objects in python, check out this [Access a function variable outside the function without using "global"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global)