# How can I make strong type object reference in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, reference, typing

I'm just beginning my adventure with Python 2.7.

I want to make some kind of strong typed reference from one class to another.

Lets say I have two classes:

```
class Module:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, m_name, m_type, m_on=False):
        self.name  = m_name
        self.type = m_type
        self.on = m_on
        self.id  = self.count
        self.count += 1
```

And `Slot` which I want to hold `Module` as element:

```
class Slot:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.id  = self.count
        self.count += 1
        self.element = None
```

Now I want to add method to set `element` in that slot and then use it in other methods (with it fields and methods) but I want to make sure that it will be element : Module.

It will be also helpful if I can "tell" PyCharm that `element` is type of `Module` so it will auto-complete my typing.

Is it even possible? Can I trick python other then:

```
self.element = Module()
```

in init method (if I do above, it recognize element as type of Module and it does auto-complete).

Answer (score 1):

As [haraprasadj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3462736/haraprasadj) says, Python is not statically typed so you should probably try to get used to that and code accordingly. Python is NOT Java. I came from Java, and it took me a while getting used to this kind of stuff, but once you do, you'll find Java's syntax unnecessarily "picky" and cluttered (well... at least, I do now)

All this said, with [new style classes](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) (classes inheriting from `object`) you can use the `@property` [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python/1594484#1594484) and create transparent *getters* and *setters* (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/python-how-does-the-property-decorator-work), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters) and [this document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property))

In your case, to enforce that the `element` attribute of the `Slot` class is always `None` or an instance of `Module`, you can do the following:

```
class Module(object):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, m_name, m_type, m_on=False):
        self.name  = m_name
        self.type = m_type
        self.on = m_on
        self.id  = self.count
        self.count += 1

class Slot(object):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.id  = self.count
        self.count += 1
        self.element = None

    @property
    def element(self):
        return self._element

    @element.setter
    def element(self, e):
      if not(e is None or isinstance(e, Module)):
          raise TypeError("Element must be None or Module")
      self._element = e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Slot()
    m = Module('name', 'type')
    print "s.element? %s" % s.element
    s.element = m
    print "s.element? %s" % s.element
    # Now, exception:
    s.element = "hellouuuu"
```

Which outputs:

```
s.element? None
s.element? <__main__.Module object at 0x26c9b10>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stack13.py", line 35, in <module>
    s.element = "hellouuuu"
  File "./stack13.py", line 25, in element
    raise TypeError("Element must be None or Module")
TypeError: Element must be None or Module
```

Ok, what's happening here? When you create an instance of `Slot` (variable `s`) and you try to assign something to its `module` attribute using `s.module = "whatever"`, what's actually happening is that the `@element.setter` method of `s` is called, with `"whatever"` as the `e` parameter. If the method doesn't throw an exception, the actual attribute is stored in `s._module`) You can examine the actual attributes of the class using `vars(s)` (see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) about `vars`):

```
>> s = Slot()
>> m = Module('name', 'type')
>> s.element = m
>> print "%s" % vars(s)
{'count': 1, 'id': 0, '_element': <__main__.Module object at 0x19d0b10>}
```

See? Thre's no `element` there, but `_element`

Now, when you try to read the `element` attribute, using `s.element`, what's happening is that the method decorated with `@property` is being called.

In the example I posted, add a `print` statement in that method:

```
@property
def element(self):
    print "I'm reading self._element. Wohooo"
    return self._element
```

Now, re-execute the script. You'll see this in the output:

```
I'm reading self._element. Wohooo
s.element? None
I'm reading self._element. Wohooo
s.element? <__main__.Module object at 0x1fd0ad0>
{'count': 1, 'id': 0, '_element': <__main__.Module object at 0x1fd0ad0>}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stack13.py", line 37, in <module>
    s.element = "hellouuuu"
  File "./stack13.py", line 26, in element
    raise TypeError("Element must be None or Module")
TypeError: Element must be None or Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean static typed reference, not strong typed reference. Python references ARE strong typed.

If you want static typed, Python is not the way to go.

I don't also think there is any trickery in the statement:

```
self.element = Module()
```

This just creates an object of class Module. Also the type of variable 'element' remains Module class unless you do an explicit reassignment to another type.

This is different from what we do in C++ or Java, but this flexibility adds to the power of Python in my opinion

Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to say I want to avoid calling "constructor" - as you can see it assigns ID. Can I have many __init__ methods?

Comment: From what I understand, you can create another method in the Slot class (say, set_element) which takes a Module as input parameter. Or , if you want element to be set the moment Slot is created, you can add an input parameter to Slot's constructor to accept a Module and set that value to element. If you want to do something else entirely, I am sorry, my knowledge is also limited