# Django BooleanField accepting non-boolean type object

Tags: python, django

I have a BooleanField on Question model:

```
class Question(models.model):
    is_deleted = BooleanField()
```

Why does it accept non-boolean type python object?

```
>>>que_obj = Question.objects.create()
>>>que_obj.is_deleted='yes'
>>>que_obj.save()
>>>que_obj.is_deleted
>>>'yes'
```

Comment: Are you using SQLite ? If yes looks no further  - SQLite doesn't care about types - and switch to a real dbms (or at least an half-backed one).

Comment: @peter Actually, not true. In regular python, you'd invoke the [setter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2627034/5031339)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen ah, of course. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A model instance is just a python object. You can set any attribute to any value.

When you save the instance, all data is converted to the appropriate data types to Django's best ability. For a `BooleanField` this means that any truthy value (`bool(value) is True`) is saved as `True` and any falsy value (`bool(value) is False`) is saved as `False`.

When you save a model, the current values of the field is read, converted to an appropriate data type, and saved to the database. The original value of the field is not altered. When you reload the model from the database, the field will have the actual value saved in the database: `True`.

Comment: yes. Converted to bool type. so you say its possible to set any attribute to any value??

Comment: On a python level - yes. When you save the object, and the value is converted to a database value, you might run into an error for some field types. For example, Django can't convert `'yes'` to a valid datetime  object for a `DateTimeField`. A `BooleanField` doesn't have that problem (`bool(value)` works on any python value), so you won't  get any errors there.

Comment: clear now :) great answer. Django have method for converting value to right type.

Answer (score 0):

[peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007760/peter) is right- your line:

```
que_obj.is_deleted='yes'
```

will override the boolean value to now contain the string 'yes'. You can check the boolean value with the `bool()` function like below:

```
que_obj.is_deleted=bool('yes')
```

Here's the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=bool#bool) entry for `bool()`