# how to trigger function in another object when variable changed. Python

Tags: python

As far as I know, this is like an Observer pattern. 
Scenario: **A Center object keeps a list (queue) of all its clients.** I'm using Twisted.

1. One of client objects **changes a variable** in center object OR notify the center to change the variable,
2. and then the center object **detects the change** immediately;
3. then as soon as the detection, the center object invoke some function **of next object** in queue
4. After the client changed the variable, **the client object will be *eliminated.*** The center will take care of next client object. So I imagine there's no any function chain between these objects. So it's a little bit different from observer pattern.  (How to address this issue? Correct me if I'm wrong.)

following code is just for demo only:

```
    class client():
        def change(self):
            self.center.va = 1

        def inqueue(self):
            self.center.queue.enqueue(self)

        def function(self):
            pass

    class center():
        def __init__(self):
            self.queue = None
            self.va = 0

        ####  When the self.va changes, this func will be invoked
        def whenChanged(self):
            next = self.queue.dequeue()
            next.function()
```

Comment: Perhaps define a [setter/getter property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2627034/6779606).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever a property of class is changed, [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) function is called. You can override this by defining [`__setattr__(self, property, value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) function in your class.

You need to make your required function call within this `__ setattr__()`. Below is the sample example based on your requirement:

```
class Centre(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = None
        self.va = 0

    def whenChanged(self):
        next = self.queue.dequeue()
        next.function()

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.key = value
        self.whenChanged()  # <-- Your function
```

Whenever you will attempt to change the value of any of class's property, this `__settattr__` function will be called.

Comment: I'm using Twisted, and it seems that I cannot use new-style class. Can I still use this?

Comment: It is the part of core Python. You can use it with any flavor of Python. Made an edit with sample code

Comment: you said: " this `__settattr__` function will be called."  but `__setattr__` will be called by who?

Comment: Did you checked the document linked to `__setattr__()`? Whenever a value is assigned to class's property,this function is called. For example, on doing `self.va = 9`, for assigning the value as `9`, this function is called

Comment: Yes, I checked that out. So I assume that if I have this assignment: `center.va = 9` in a `client` object, then the `center` object will invoke the `__setattr__()` and there's no function invocation chain between `center` object and `client` object, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `setattr` of only `centre` will be executed in this case.

Answer (score 10):

Make `va` a property.

```
class Center():
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = None
        self._va = 0

    @property
    def va(self):
        return self._va

    @va.setter
    def va(self, value):
        self._va = value
        self.whenChanged()

    def whenChanged(self):
        next = self.queue.dequeue()
        next.function()
```

Comment: I assume that va setter will called in first client, right? So does this solve the issue that the first client will be eliminated before this setter invocation return?

Comment: The setter is invoked immediately upon `self.center.va = 1`, before `client.change` exits, so it runs before the client goes away.

Comment: What if the client must leave while or before this invocation chain returns?

Comment: btw, i cannot sue property since I'm inheriting old style class.

Comment: You appear to have left a lot of important context out of your question.

Comment: The client is a network connection, the center is like a service. So when the connection goes out, the service seek the next connection to serve. That's basically the specific use

Comment: You can also inherit from `object` to make it a new-style class. Your question needs a lot of work before you can get a proper answer: nothing in your question inherits from anything, and there is no mention of how `center` is used that would imply it can "go away".

Comment: The center will always be there, alive. but the client will die. When the client is about to die, it wanna "notify the center that I'm going to die", then after the notification, the client dies and center will use next client in queue to serve.

Comment: The client *cannot* go away before one of its method calls exits, at least not as shown in the question. You mentioned Twisted in another comment, but make no mention of it in the question itself.

Comment: I looked at other related post, they talked about observer pattern, that's why I didn't mention twisted ---- no idea about if twisted could have an impact on this.

Comment: So the only thing I can do is polling? I don't see any fundamental solution from twisted perspective.

Comment: this should be the preferred way to the core python `__setattr__`.