# Can pycharm community edition autogenerate getters and setters

Tags: pycharm

I searched around for this and only found this article...

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/generating-getters-and-setters.html

It is a tutorial from jetbrains (makers of Pycharm) but it seems to cover one of their other IDEs, not Pycharm.  When I go to the Generate option in the PyCharm menu I see nothing about getters and setters, just class override methods.  Does an autogenerate getters and setters option exist in the community edition of Pycharm?

Comment: Try to see in the menu on top : Code => Generate. This should show u a window with generate options :)

Comment: I already did that and all I got was a popup context menu that only has override methods.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not pycharm but the way python use getters and setters ... Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters Look at the answer : The Pythonic way is to not use them (getters and setters).

Comment: @GrechkaVassili What about the second answer of this post, which have 10 times more upvotes ? It talks about the `@property` notation. Is that a bad practice or something ?

Comment: @Leogout Seems that someone already answered to that question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943813/6083123