# How to get type of object's attribute in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

assume I have the following class:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.myStr = "bla"
        self.myInt = number * 3
```

how do I get the the attributes types? I mean I want to get the following list: ['str','int']?

I also want it to work on derived classes.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why not `['int', 'str']`?

Comment: A Pythonic way is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters) :-)

Answer (score 12):

RHP almost has it. You want to combine the `dir`, `type`, and `getattr` functions. A comprehension like this should be what you want:

```
o = myClass(1)
[type(getattr(o, name)).__name__ for name in dir(o) if name[:2] != '__' and name[-2:] != '__']
```

This will give you `['int', 'str']` (because `myInt` sorts before `myStr` in alpha-order).

Breaking it down:

1. `getattr` looks up the name of an attribute on an object
2. `type` gets the type of an object
3. `__name__` on a `type` gives the string name of the type
4. `dir` lists *all* attributes on an object (including `__dunder__` attributes)
5. the `if` test in the comprehension filters out the `__dunder__` attributes

Comment: is there any easy way to check if a certain class has attribute of some derived object?

Comment: `dir` lists _all_ attributes on an object; if the object's class inherits from another class, an instance of that object will have all the attributes on both.

Comment: I have a tiny problem with your solution: in some cases I get inside the list - "'instancemethod'".

Comment: That would be from an object having methods as attributes. Methods are members of an object, too. You can filter these out by splitting up the list comprehension, and removing items if the result of `type` has a `__call__` attribute.

Comment: sorry, but I maybe wasn't clear enough. I want to know the type of objects that show up as 'instance' and 'instancemethod'. I guess these are the attributes that were inherited. that was my first problem.

Comment: Those _are_ the types of objects. `instancemethod` is the type of a method attribute, it is a function with `self` bound to the first argument.

Comment: I think I should reopen another question

Answer (score 0):

Use the type() function. You can even use it to print out the variable type like this:

```
print(type(variable_name))
```

Comment: Suppose you find out this information. How do you expect it to *help you*? You should explain more about what you are *really trying to do*.