# Read-Only properties without getters

Tags: python, oop

I was reading [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters) about using getters in Python, quote:

> The Pythonic way is to not use them. If you must have them then hide
>   them behind a property.

That same page includes various examples, but my question is, if getters are not the Python way, how would I indicate to someone reading my code that a variable should be read-only after construction.

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, ID, name, tire, engine):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.tire = tire
        self.engine = engine

    def __str__(self):
        return "ID: {0} Name:{1} Tire: {2} Engine: {3}".format(self.ID, self.name, self.tire, self.engine)
```

If I wanted to indicate to another developer that `self.engine` is read-only after being set in the `constructor`, how would I do so? In orders words, if clients violate the rule, and attempt to set it, it's there problem if the implementation of `self.engine` changes(for example, from object of the class `Engine` to `Dictionary`).

Comment: Give it a single underscore prefix e.g `self._engine`. It wont stop others from using it but it is a clear indicator its private. You can also use a double underscore prefix to have python mangle the name (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name) for details.

Comment: @PaulRooney No, the underscore indicates that the variable shouldn't be accessed from outside of the class at all (except from derived classes).

Comment: I don't mind if they get it, just that they aren't allowed to set it afterward(i'm aware there is nothing really stopping them from doing so).

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'm not clear on where your disagreement lies.

Comment: @S.R. Right. If you don't want to use properties you could list the accessible variables in the doc-string of the class and mention something like "(read-write)" or "(read-only) for each.

Comment: @PaulRooney - He saying the underscore should be treated as protected variables

Comment: @S.R. and so was I, so it would seem there is no disagreement on that point.

Comment: @PaulRooney The OP wanted a read-only variable just by documentation (without `property`) but without property, an underscored variable is by convention meant to be `protected` in Java/C++ notion.

Comment: Why not just define a _docstring_ for your property and treat the users of your class as consenting adults?

Comment: @zwer - I think you've got it, any attempt to set it after being warned with the docstring is there problem, not mine.

Comment: I think the quote from the link is just wrong (or poorly worded). Properties are the Pythonic way and they need of course a hidden getter (and maybe setter, deleter) function behind it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher - Agreed, that being said I selected the answer below on how to use them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator and not define a setter to communicate that `engine` should not be modified:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, ID, name, tire, engine):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.tire = tire
        self._engine = engine

    def __str__(self):
        return "ID: {0} Name:{1} Tire: {2} Engine: {3}".format(self.ID, self.name, self.tire, self.engine)

    @property
    def engine(self):
        return self._engine
```

Note that the user can still go around the property and set `_engine` directly.

Note that the `@property` decorator only works with new style classes.

Comment: the `@properly` keyword will work with classes even if they don't inherit object, at least in Python 3 anyway. As stated in my question and the link `@property` is not the Python way of doing it apparently.

Comment: @S.R. no, you are not understanding that link. Properties are the Pythonic way.

Comment: @S.R. I think the answer you linked is referring to defining methods like `get_thing` and `set_thing`, not using `@property`. The documentation for this facility basically describes this use case: "A typical use is to define a managed attribute x". See the specific example for the read only property `voltage`.

Comment: @Galen - I think your right, I've been using `property` this way as described by you and the docs, but seeing that other link made me question if I was doing the right thing.

Comment: @S.R. In Python 3, all classes are new style classes and happen to inherit from `object`. Old style classes were removed. I will edit my answer to avoid confusion.