# Passing self as method parameter within class - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, parameters, parameter-passing

I am using Python 3 and I want to simulate a card game with my Card class below:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, name = "", stars = 0, attack = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.stars = stars
        self.attack = attack

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def setStars(self, stars):
        self.stars = stars

    def getStars(self):
        return self.stars

    def setAttack(self, attack):
        self.attack = attack

    def getAttack(self):
        return self.attack

    def attack(self, enemyCard):
        print(self.name + "attacked" + enemyCard.getName() + "and did" + self.attack + "damage!")
```

The following is my driver class:

```
def main():
    me = Card()
    me.setName("Good")
    me.setStars(99)
    me.setAttack(9000)

    you = Card()
    you.setName("EVIL")
    you.setStars(0)
    you.setAttack(-1)

    me.attack(you)      <-error here
```

Everything works except at the very last line which is *me.attack(you)*:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I think it may have something to do with my *attack* method in *Card* but I don't quite understand why the variable *you* is seen as an int

Comment: Your class has an attribute named `attack` _and_ a function named `attack`. You'll have to rename one of the two.

Comment: While you are at it, get rid of all your `get*` and `set*` functions. They don't do anything except wrap simple attribute access, so just access the attributes directly.

Comment: It's complaining that `me.attack` is an `int`, not a function, so it can't be applied to `you`. Unless you rename the attribute or the method, you'll have to write `Card.attack(me, you)` instead.

Comment: In addition to @chepner's comment, also see [_What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: @chepner What if some more processing is needed? Getters and Setters are not necessarily bad

Comment: @Adonis use the `property` decorator. See the question I linked to above.

Comment: @Adonis The nice thing about properties is that they maintain backwards compatibility with attributes. If existing code uses `me.attack = 3`, then changing `attack` from a simple attribute to a property doesn't require any changes to the existing code.

Comment: the problem is in your `constructor` and `setAttack` and `getAttack` method, change the name of instance variable different than method name `attack` and things will work

Comment: See also https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup.