# Python - How to edit a class object value automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I change a class object with some rules when it assigned?
for example:

```
class Foo:
    x=0
    if x < 0:
        x = -1
    else:
        x = 1


p = Foo()
p.x = 1234
print(p.X)
```

So when I print p.x I expect 1 to be printed. but 1234 is printed. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! this might helpes you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters

Comment: Use `self.x` instead of `x`

Comment: Do you want to set the class property `Foo.x`  or the object property `p.x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make `x` a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), with a setter function:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            value = -1
        else:
            value = 1

        self._x = value
```

This makes it so the function decorated with `@x.setter` is executed whenever an assignment to the `x` attribute is performed:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.x = 1234
>>> foo.x
1
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks :)

Comment: You should initialize `self.x` in `Foo.__init__` else trying to read `x` before setting it will raise an attribute error.

Answer (score 1):

The first `x = 0` you declare is a *class attribute*. It is the same for all objects of the class.

When you write `p.x`, you create an *instance attribute*, a value of `x` that belongs to that specific object. That hides the `Foo.x` in that particular object (that's how the python attribute lookup works).

However, that value remains the default for other objects of the class, eg, if you create a new object

```
foo2 = Foo()
print(f2.x) # prints 1
```