# How to increase an object attribute by a variable amount

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a class in python for a figure with attributes name, health, strength, stealth, agility, weapons and money. There is a shop in the game I'm making to increase the value of any of the integer properties with a specific item. Each integer property can be increased by one of two different items with a different cost and buff strength. The issue I'm having is actually incrementing the attribute by the amount and saving the object.

Here's the code for the object:

```
class Figure:
    def __init__(self, stats):
        #create figure object
        self.name = stats[0]
        self.health = int(stats[1])
        self.strength = int(stats[2])
        self.stealth = int(stats[3])
        self.agility = int(stats[4])
        self.weapons = int(stats[5])
        self.money = int(stats[6])

    def show_person(self):
        #show object attributes
        print("\n\n{}\n\nHealth: {}\nStrength: {}\nStealth: {}\nCunning: {}\nWeapons: {}\nMoney: £{}".format(self.name.title(),self.health,self.strength,self.stealth,self.cunning,self.weapons, self.money))

    def set_attr(self,attr,buff):
        #increase character attribute by a variable amount
        eval("self.{} = self.{} + {}".format(attr,attr,buff))
```

I might put `friend.set_attr("stealth",10)` to increase friend's value of stealth by 10 where friend is a variable that contains one of these Figure objects but this error is thrown:

```
File Computer Science\python\oop game.py", line 21, in set_attr
  exec(eval("self.{} = self.{} + {}".format(attr,attr,buff)))
File "<string>", line 1
  self.agility = self.agility + 4
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I can't work out why.

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary with attribute names as key instead of several variables? That way you could access the values by their names `self.attribs["agility"]` instead of using `eval`.

Comment: Why don't you just do `friend.stealth = 10`?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters

Comment: ["The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: The code in the traceback doesn't match the code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment is a statement and cannot be used inside an `eval`, which accepts only expressions. You should use `exec` instead:

```
exec("self.{} = self.{} + {}".format(attr,attr,buff))
```

But instead of `exec`, it's better to use the `setattr` function:

```
setattr(self, attr, getattr(self, attr) + buff)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `exec` and `eval`. Use `getattr` and `setattr`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def set_attr(self, attr, buff):
        new_val = getattr(self, attr) + buff
        setattr(self, attr, new_val)

foo = Foo()
foo.set_attr('x', 10)
print(foo.x)
# 10
foo.set_attr('x', 11)
print(foo.x)
# 21
```

Alternatively it is possible to use `vars` to modify the attribute directly (which personally I tend to like less):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def set_attr(self, attr, buff):
        vars(self)[attr] += buff

foo = Foo()
foo.set_attr('x', 10)
print(foo.x)
# 10
foo.set_attr('x', 11)
print(foo.x)
# 21
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear: you know you could just type

```
a.foo += 2
```

If yes, but you need the other method:

Python already has internal functions that does *exactly* what you're trying to achieve.
The methods are called `setattr` and `getattr`. Read more about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr). For now, here's how you can use them:

```
class A:
   b = 3

a = A()

setattr(a, 'b', 5)
print(a.b) # 5
print(getattr(a, 'b')) # 5

setattr(a, 'b', getattr(a, 'b') + 5)
print(a.b) # 10
```

So you could implement a method that increments an attribute like this:

```
class A:
   def incr_attr(self, attr_name, amount):
      setattr(self, attr_name, getattr(self, attr_name) + amount)
```

Or, even more convenient:

```
def incr_attrs(self, **attr_map):
    for attr_name, amount in attr_map.items():
         setattr(self, attr_name, getattr(self, attr_name) + amount)
```

So you can type

```
A.incr_attr(stealth=3, money=10)
```