# Python getter method with one line or directly reference attributes

Tags: python, attributes

Say I have a python class which may set a dictionary upon instantiating:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, some_dict=None):
        self.some_dict = some_dict
```

and then in another place in my code, I want to look up a key in that dict - but of course only if it exists. Is the best Python style then to 1) make a "checking method" in the class, even if it's only one line, or 2) directly reference the class' dictionary attribute? Let's say the class was instantiated as `myClassInstance` the options are then

1) Class method:

```
    def is_key_in_dict(self, query_key):
        return self.some_dict and query_key in self.some_dict
```

which is then used as

```
if myClassInstance.is_key_in_dict(query_key):
    do_something()
```

or, 2) directly reference in the code where its used.

```
if myClassInstance.some_dict and query_key in myClassInstance.some_dict:
    do_something()
```

Is it okay (style-wise) to reference class attributes directly or is it considered bad/unsafe practice? I am somewhat familiar with the `@property` decorator, as discussed in this post: [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters), but not sure if that answers my question.

Comment: I wouldn't do either of these. I'd set the attribute to an empty dict if the parameter is none, then just do the `if...in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [EAFP-Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python), using exceptions for control flow is pythonic. Currently, you are looking before you leap.

I would code (either as a function or method):

```
def do_something(myClassInstance, query_key): # additional arguments omitted
    try:
        query_value = myClassInstance.some_dict[query_key]
    except TypeError, KeyError: # could also consider AttributeError
        pass # or whatever logic you need
    else: # no exception
        # code that does something
```

If you have multiple functions/methods that need the same exception handling, for reusability it would make sense to write an additional wrapper around the exception handling which returns `query_value` if no exception occured and a appropriate sentinel value (e.g. `None`) if an exception occured.

You could also consider to use the line

```
self.some_dict = some_dict or {}
```

in `__init__`, then you don't have to think about `TypeError`s any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need
[object.__contains__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, some_dict):
        self.some_dict = some_dict or {}

    def __contains__(self, item):

        if item in self.some_dict:
            return True

        return False
```

And in your code

```
c = SomeClass({'a': 1})

if 'a' in c:
    print('c contains key "a"')
```