# Python 3 : Getter is not returning the data it should be

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I have a parent Class that has a setter that returns queryFiltre value and a getter that is supposed to pass the queryFiltre value to my child Class. queryFiltre Should return an SQL query like "SELECT * FROM Report WHERE GA_RPM > 0 and CAMPAIGN LIKE '%TT%'... ".

The print() in the setter returns a SQL query, but the print() of the getter when called in the child Class returns something like " <**main**.SimpleGrid object at 0x042AF2B0>".

What's wrong with my code? Please bear with me as I'm still learning and oop is still an abstract concept in my head.

I've added comments in the code so you can see what happens where:

```
class SimpleGrid(gridlib.Grid): ##, mixins.GridAutoEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)


        ########### DATABASE CONNECT 
        self.path =os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self.dbfile = os.path.join(self.path , "report.db")
        self.db_conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbfile)
        self.theCursor =  self.db_conn.cursor()
        ########### SETTING FILE CONNECT 
        self.configFile = os.path.join(self.path , "config.ini")
        self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read(self.configFile)

        ########### Calling th Getter and Setter
        self.queryFiltre = self.setQueryFiltre(self)
        self.getQueryFiltre()

    ########### Setter
    def setQueryFiltre(self,queryFiltre):

            if self.config.get('Network', 'taboola') == "true" and self.config.get('Network', 'ob') == "true":
                network = ""
            elif self.config.get('Network', 'taboola') == "true" and self.config.get('Network', 'ob') == "false":
                network = " and CAMPAIGN LIKE '%TB%'"
            elif self.config.get('Network', 'outbrain') == "true" and self.config.get('Network', 'tb') == "false":
                network = " and CAMPAIGN LIKE '%OB%'"
            else:
                network = ""

            queryFiltre = "SELECT * FROM Report WHERE  GA_RPM > 0 " + network + "  and STATUS = '1' ORDER BY CLICKS DESC"

            ########### The print below returns the right value of queryFiltre
            print(queryFiltre)

            return queryFiltre

        ########### Getter
        def getQueryFiltre(queryFiltre):
            queryFiltre = queryFiltre
            return queryFiltre


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, 0, "Native Ads Reports V1.0", size=(1400,800))
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self, log)

        ########### Calling the Getter of the parent Class
        self.queryFiltre = self.grid.getQueryFiltre()

        ########### DATABASE CONNECT
        self.path =os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self.dbfile = os.path.join(self.path , "report.db")
        self.db_conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbfile)
        self.theCursor =  self.db_conn.cursor()

        ########### The print below returns a bad value, something like : <__main__.SimpleGrid object at 0x042AF2B0>
        print(self.queryFiltre)
```

You'll notice also that I've added the script to define the path and to connect to the db in both classes, is there a way to do it only once in the first Class?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getQueryFiltre()` in `SimpleGrid` has the wrong indentation, and is missing the first argument `self`. The way you've written it, it is a function within the scope of your `setQueryFiltre()`, and it isn't called from anywhere.

It should be indented to the same level as `setQueryFiltre`, and have a first argument `self`.

By the way, you shouldn't be using getters. It's not pythonic, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943813/11451509

Comment: Which getQueryFiltre() are you talking about, if it's the call in the parent Class, I receive "getQueryFiltre() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: And this is not working too : def getQueryFiltre(self, queryFiltre):
        self.queryFiltre = queryFiltre
        return self.queryFiltre

Comment: @CreekBarbara I've updated my answer. Hope it is clear now.