# Changing variables for later use in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to set a variable and be able to change and store that variable using set and gets. The current output is:

0

0

I'm trying to get it to be:

0

2

Can some one help me understand how to change a value and then use it later in python? Kind of like a toggle?

```
class Spammer: 
    def __init__(self, spam = 0): 
        self._spam = spam 

        # getter method 
    def get_spam(self): 
            return self._spam 

        # setter method 
    def set_spam(self, x): 
     if x == 1:  
         return self._spam+1

     if x== 0:
         return self._spam
 spammer=Spammer()

 print (spammer.get_spam())
 spammer.set_spam(1)
 print(spammer.get_spam())
```

Comment: `set_spam()` returns a value, but it never actually sets the value of self.spam.  Is that intentional?

Comment: set the value of `self._spam` in `set_spam`, just like you did in `__init__`

Comment: `set_spam` is a misleading name, and probably doesn't need to return a value. Also, it's unclear why you would want to call `set_spam` with an argument of 0, rather than just not call it in the first place.

Comment: Using setters and getters is not Pythonic, you can just directly access the attribute like `spammer._spam` and `spammer._spam = 1`. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943813/3620725

Answer (score 0):

There is an @property decorator builtin so you could do the following:

```py
class Spammer: 
    def __init__(self, spam = 0): 
        self._spam = spam 

    @property
    def spam(self): 
        return self._spam

    @spam.setter
    def spam(self, new_spam):
        self._spam = new_spam
```

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you! 
I'm stupid new at this