# Python Setter and Getter Naming

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to understand how getters and setters work in python with properties, but I'm confused in the naming convention.

Is there a specific naming standard for the getter and setter?  Why do I need to set the returning name of parameter with an "_" (underscore)?  If I were to change it to just "self.color" instead of "self._color", the getter and setter no longer work.  Also, if I were to change the name of the functions the print function is no longer is executed.  Any clarification would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
class FavoriteColor:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    @property
    def color(self):
        print('getter method')
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, x):
        print('setter method')
        self._color = x

obj1 = FavoriteColor('blue')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did this:

```
@color.setter
def color(self, x):
    self.color = x
```

Then this setter would call itself repeatedly. There's no difference between `obj1.color = 'blue'` and `self.color = x`, they both do the same thing, which is to invoke the setter `def color`. So with the setter invoking itself recursively, you have an endless recursive loop which will eventually crash your program.

For that purpose you need to actually store the value on *some other attribute.* Using "`_color`" for its name is just the rather obvious solution.

Note that using this kind of setter/getter in Python is frowned upon, if your setter/getter doesn't *do* anything. You can remove them entirely and just plainly set `self.color = 'blue'` for exactly the same effect as your setter/getter pair currently has. You should only use setters/getters if they do some additional processing. Since the syntax of a plain attribute and a setter/getter are identical, you can even safely transition to using setters/getters later on if you need to (in contrast to, say, Java, where a setter/getter is `foo.setBar(...)`, which is not identical to `foo.bar = ...` and cannot be transparently substituted later).

Comment: `you can even safely transition to using setters/getters later on if you need to `: googlers, more info + code examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters; tldr use `@property` right before `def`

Answer (score 2):

I guess the confusing part is in the `__init__`. The `self.color = color` in `__init__` is actually calling your setter, which creates the private variable called `_color`. The setter and getter work as wrappers of this private `_color` allowing you to do something extra than accessing the raw variable directly.

I don't know if this is a common practice to call setter in `__init__`, but I prefer to defining the wrapped private variable in `__init__` directly. To me it looks more straightforward

```py
class FavoriteColor:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self._color = color
```

Answer (score 1):

Like most of the programming languages, Python has convention to define private variables of a class with an underscore "_", so by naming "_color" we are meant to create a private attribute 'color'.

And for your second question, you are meant to define getter setter property for the attribute that you just defined, According to rules of property decorator, we must have to define same name of getter setter methods as that of our targeted attribute along with @property decorator.

Hope it helps

```
class FavoriteColor:
     def __init__(self, color): 
          self._color = color

     # a getter funcion
     @property
     def color(self): 
         return self._color 

     # a setter function 
     @color.setter 
     def color(self, value): 
        self._color = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Python variables and functions share the same namespace. Thus `self.color` can only refer to either the getter/setter method, or the attribute itself. A common convention is to add an underscore to the internal attribute name, to avoid this naming clash, which also conventionally conveys the notion that it is a private attribute.

This should already explain your other question. If you have a method named `self.color` and it contains code where it replaces *itself* with a value, then of course you can no longer use `self.color` to refer to the method again.

Let's look at that again with an even simpler example.

```
>>> class X:
...   def color (self, value):
...     self.color = value
```

The first time you call the function - say, `xinstance.color("red")` - it will set the instance's `color` to `"red"`. So then you can no longer call `xinstance.color()` again because it is now a string, not a function.

Adding the `@property` decorator changes this somewhat, because now `self.color = value` will cause `color` to call itself, which causes it to call itself, which causes it to call itself again, etc.

Comment: The setter wouldn't replace itself, it would just call itself recursively. And your `def` example also wouldn't replace `def color`, it just creates a local variable `color`.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for feedback -- updated with an actually tested example (-:

Comment: Better, but the second paragraph still suggests that the setter is replacing itself, which it isn't.