# Dynamic Property Getter and Setter

Tags: python

Is there a way I can create a class with varied number of attributes and create corresponding getters and setters for these attributes?

My sample code is shown below.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **options):
        self._options = options
        for key, value in options.items():
            setattr(self, f"_{key.lower()}", value)
            setattr(self, f"get_{key.lower()}", lambda : getattr(self, f"_{key.lower()}", None))


a = A(dimension = 2, name = "Unknown Alphabet")

for key, value in a.__dict__.items():
    print(f"A[{key.lower()}] = {value}")

print(a.get_name())
print(a.get_dimension())

new_santa_clause = A(location = "North Pole", vehicle = "Teleportation", naughty_kids_list = [])
for key, value in new_santa_clause.__dict__.items():
    print(f"SantaClause[{key}] = {value}")

print(new_santa_clause.get_location())
print(new_santa_clause.get_vehicle())
print(new_santa_clause.get_naughty_kids_list())
```

Output of execution is shown below

```
A[_options] = {'dimension': 2, 'name': 'Unknown Alphabet'}
A[_dimension] = 2
A[get_dimension] = <function A.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002334B4EC678>
A[_name] = Unknown Alphabet
A[get_name] = <function A.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002334B4EC1F8>
Unknown Alphabet
Unknown Alphabet
SantaClause[_options] = {'location': 'North Pole', 'vehicle': 'Teleportation', 'naughty_kids_list': []}
SantaClause[_location] = North Pole
SantaClause[get_location] = <function A.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002334B4ECA68>
SantaClause[_vehicle] = Teleportation
SantaClause[get_vehicle] = <function A.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002334B4EC438>
SantaClause[_naughty_kids_list] = []
SantaClause[get_naughty_kids_list] = <function A.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002334B4ECCA8>
[]
[]
[]
```

The values are getting set properly and getters are also getting created properly. Its just that when the getters are executed, proper values are not returned.

Comment: you don't need getter and setters like this in python.

Comment: Why not just use a dict?

Comment: Python is case-sensitive, so why are you using `key.lower()`?

Comment: Getters and setters are strongly discouraged in Python, but you could use a `property` instead. See [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627002/4518341)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can do what you want *to some extent*, but in Python, properties are looked-up based in the **`class`** of an object, which means you would need to create a separate class for each combination of attributes you wanted (which must be called to create an instance of it).

##### Explanation

In the code below defines a function named `make_class()` to replace the generic `A` class in your question. It handles [mutable default arguments](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221224620id_/http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) properly by automatically detecting them and assigning *copies* of their values to the class instance attributes when one is created (preventing all instance from sharing a single class-level attribute).

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping, MutableSequence, MutableSet
import copy

MUTABLES = MutableMapping, MutableSequence, MutableSet  # Mutable containers

def make_class(classname, **options):
    """Return a class with the specified attributes implemented as properties.
    """
    class Class:
        def __init__(self):
            """Initialize instance attribute storage name values."""
            for key, value in options.items():
                if isinstance(value, MUTABLES):  # Mutable?
                    value = copy.deepcopy(value)  # Avoid mutable default arg.
                setattr(self, '_' + key.lower(), value)

    for key, value in options.items():  # Create class' properties.
        setattr(Class, key.lower(), managed_attribute(key))

    Class.__name__ = classname
    return Class

def managed_attribute(name):
    """Return a property that stores values under a private non-public name."""
    storage_name = '_' + name.lower()

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return getattr(self, storage_name)

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        setattr(self, storage_name, value)

    return prop


A = make_class('A', dimension=2, name="Unknown Alphabet")
a = A()
print(a.name)       # -> Unknown Alphabet
print(a.dimension)  # -> 2


SantaClaus = make_class('SantaClaus', location="North Pole", vehicle="Teleportation",
                        naughty_kids_list=[])

santa_clause = SantaClaus()
print(santa_clause.location)           # -> North Pole
print(santa_clause.vehicle)            # -> Teleportation
print(santa_clause.naughty_kids_list)  # -> []
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a pythonic way to achieve what you want (use a property). But it's interesting to understand what's happening.

Let's focus on a slightly modified version of your code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **options):
        for key, value in options.items():
            setattr(self, f"get_{key}", lambda: value)

a = A(x=1, y=2)

print(a.get_x()) # 2
print(a.get_y()) # 2
```

What is the meaning of `lambda: value`? A function that returns `value`. Yes, but not any function. This function is a closure, that has access to a reference of the local variable `value` of `A.__init__`. And what is the value of `value` at the end of the initialization? The last `value` of the loop, that is `2`.

When you call `a.get_x()`, the interpreter locates the attribute `get_x` of `a`: this is a closure. It then locates the value of `value`, that is 2, and executes the lambda function: return `value`, ie `return 2`.

Comment: Yes as you had described the values being printing are the same for all getters created this way. I tried printing the method object to see if the created methods were pointing to same method or different methods. They had different method addresses but I am guessing all the methods were doing something like this 

def f():
      return 2

In the first run the lambda function must have pointed to a constant function that just returned the value 1.

What I was trying to do is create a actual getter that could query the private attribute value and return it.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by @wjandrea explain the use of @property, @attribute.setter and @attribute.deleter, but it's not realy needed here, e.g. because you want "read-only" property or additional functionality in the setter. This will do just fine:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

foo = Foo(spam='SPAM', eggs="EGGS")
print(foo.spam)
print(foo.eggs)

# assign new value to foo.spam
foo.spam='bar'
print(foo.spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing [isn't really pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943813/355230) nor is it creating a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property). It's merely creating private instance attribute that has a `lambda` "getter" method.

The problem is with the way your `lambda` expression in the `for` loop uses the `key` variable, which gets assigned a different value each iteration of the `for` loop — and the result is at the end all of the separate "getter" functions will be referring to the same variable which will have *last value* that it was assigned to in the `for` loop.
To avoid this and fix your code you can supply a ["default parameter value"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) for `key` when creating the `lambda` "getter" function as shown below:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **options):
#        self._options = options  # NOT NEEDED.
        for key, value in options.items():
            setattr(self, f"_{key.lower()}", value)
            # CHANGED: added default parameter value to lambda in next statement.
            setattr(self, f"get_{key.lower()}", 
                    lambda key=key: getattr(self, f"_{key.lower()}", None))
```