# What does the property python builtin do?

Tags: python

I found in  **builtins** python objects a one named  **property**. The docstring for this says:
*Typical use is to define a managed attribute x:*
But I don't understend what that means

Could someone explain when and for what we must use this?

Comment: Not exactly duplicates, but [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627002/364696) and [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160/364696) should answer your question.

Comment: Wow, nothing in python is transparent. Thanks!

Comment: The [online documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) is typically more detailed than the docstrings.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  To wit, "Search, and research".  You should have a specific question regarding the documentation, not a generic request to explain the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Note that builtins will return standard built-in objects in python3, It provides direct access to all ‘built-in’ identifiers of Python. You can find more information in https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html

```
   >>> import builtins
   >>> vars(globals()['__builtins__']) is vars(builtins)
    True
```

Comment: The question is about `property`, not about `builtins`.

Answer (score 0):

What a builtin.property does is that takes your property and returns attributes for different style classes and what that means that it will be classes that come from an object. What a builtin does is that it is made up of many different functions that are built in, which is obvious but the typical use is to give an attribute about x. This below is an example. If you need any other on builtins or other python Functions go to https://help.kite.com/article/63-using-the-copilot That is where I got the Example. If you want to find more detail about the example type in the search builtin.property. **Typical use is to define a managed attribute x that means to return the featureless object x**

```
 class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def getx(self):
        return self._x
    def setx(self, value):
        self._x = value
    def delx(self):
        del self._x
    x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
```