# How can I access methods of list objects using a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, list

I created this class:

```
class Family:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = ""
        self.__address = ""
        self.__age = ""
        self.__phone = ""

    # Mutator Methods
    def setName (self,mName):
        self.__name = mName
    def setAddress (self,mAddress):
        self.__address = mAddress
    def setAge (self,mAge):
        self.__age = mAge
    def setPhone (self,mPhone):
        self.__phone = mPhone

    # Accessor Methods
    def getName():
        return __name
    def getAddress():
        return __address
    def getAge():
        return __age
    def getPhone():
        return __phone
```

Using the main module, I created three instances of the family class and put them in a list.

```
def main():
    objectOne = familyClass.Family()
    objectTwo = familyClass.Family()
    objectThree = familyClass.Family()

    membersList = [objectOne,objectTwo,objectThree]
```

I, then, created a loop that asks the user to input the information for each object then another loop to print out the information:

```
    for index in range(0,3):
        membersList[index].setName = input("Enter the name: ")
        membersList[index].setAddress = input("Enter the address: ")
        membersList[index].setAge = input("Enter the age: ")
        membersList[index].setPhone = input("Enter the phone: ")
        print()

    for index in range(0,3):
        print("Here's the family members entered:")
        print('Name: {}'.format(membersList[index].getName))
        print('Address: {}'.format(membersList[index].getAddress))
        print('Age: {}'.format(membersList[index].getAge))
        print('Phone: {}'.format(membersList[index].getPhone))
        print()
```

but I kept getting this:

```
Here's the family members entered:
Name: <bound method Family.getName of <familyClass.Family object at 0x106264970>>
Address: <bound method Family.getAddress of <familyClass.Family object at 0x106264970>>
Age: <bound method Family.getAge of <familyClass.Family object at 0x106264970>>
Phone: <bound method Family.getPhone of <familyClass.Family object at 0x106264970>>
```

Comment: As the output says, you got the *method* objects. It seems you expected to get their return values, so you actually have to *call* them using `()`.

Comment: You may want to read a basic Python OOP tutorial. You generally don't need getter /setter in Python, and should use property to implement them. Also, `__init__` should generally take the parameters with which to initialise the fields, not assign bogus values.

Comment: Its a homework problem and the instructor wanted us to use accessor and mutator functions instead of the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 problem:
1 - in your getter method you omit to use `self`

```
 # Accessor Methods 
 def getName(self): 
     return self.__name
 def getAddress(self):
     return self.__add
 def getAge(self): 
     return self.__age 
 def getPhone(): 
     return self.__phone
```

2 - you need to call your set with `()` like this `a.setName( input("Enter the name: "))` because is `method` and `not attribute`
 read here  [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters)

example :

```
In [63]: a = Family()                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [64]: a.setName( input("Enter the name: "))                                                                                                                                                             
Enter the name: blah

In [65]: a.getName()                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[65]: 'blah'

In [66]:
```