# Using the @property decorator versus defining a variable within a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

What is the difference between using the @property decorator as a "getter" and just defining the variable normally?

See an example below:

```
Class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self, ....):
      ....


   @property
   def headers(self):
      return {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

Versus:

```
Class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self, ....):
      .....

   self.headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

Why use one over the other? When should the property decorator be used?

Comment: Property is a pythonic implementation of *getters* and *setters* which is part of OOP.

Comment: a very thorough explanation of decorators: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators/1594484#1594484

Comment: To elaborate on @OlvinRoght answer a bit, you can add some custom logic when getting/setting a property, which is not possible in case of class variables.

Comment: The beauty of the `property` class is that you can start with a publicly exposed attribute, and if you decide *later* that it should be protected by a getter and/or setter, you can do so without changing the *interface*.

Comment: @chepner So I'd use the ```property``` decorator when I wanted to keep the attribute private/unmodifiable?

Comment: Yes, that's one reason to create a property without a setter.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters