# I tried adding a new attribute to one of my classes but I get an error message

Tags: python, class

So I added the id attribute to my class and I get this error:

File "C:\Users\Home pc\PycharmProjects\proiect final\domain\music.py", line 49, in **eq**
if self._id == other.id:
AttributeError: 'Music' object has no attribute 'id'

I am working in python 3.8

And this is my class

```
class Music:

    def __init__(self, title, artist, genre, duration, id):
        self._title = title
        self._artist = artist
        self._genre = genre
        self._duration = duration
        self._id = id

    def get_title(self):
        return self._title

    def get_artist(self):
        return self._artist

    def get_genre(self):
        return self._genre

    def get_duration(self):
        return self._duration

    def get_id(self):
        return self._id

    def set_title(self, title):
        self._title = title

    def set_artist(self, artist):
        self._artist = artist

    def set_genre(self, genre):
        self._genre = genre

    def set_duration(self, duration):
        self._duration = duration

    def set_id(self, id):
        self._id = id

    def __repr__(self):
         return "Title: {0}, Artist: {1}, Genre: {2}, Duration: {3} , Id: {4}".format(self._title, self._artist, self._genre,
                                                                               self._duration, self._id)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Title: {0}, Artist: {1}, Genre: {2}, Duration: {3}, Id: {4}".format(self._title, self._artist, self._genre,
                                                                               self._duration, self._id)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self._id == other.id:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: `other.id` -> `other._id`

Comment: You probably meant `other._id` (with the underscore).

Comment: Maybe `other._id` ?

Comment: I think at comparison you have to do others._id

Comment: Why is your code full of getters and setters? That's not really how Python classes work. You might be interested in `@property` though. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943813/4799172) for example.

Answer (score 1):

In your method to check for equality `__eq__`, you're checking for `other.id` instead of `other._id`. `id`is not a property of your class Music, as we see in `__init__`.

You have created methods for your class Music to access their attributes, yet in `__eq__` you're directly accessing them. This issue could be solved by writing:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.get_id()== other.get_id():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And your `__eq__` method could be further simplified:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.get_id()== other.get_id()
```

Comment: There's no problem accessing private attributes directly from within the class though.

Comment: I agree with you, Ted, but since he made the methods, it's also perfectly fine to use them within the class. It would also have saved him this problem