# Can shorthand operators be used with getters and setters?

Tags: python

Is it possible to set a property with shorthand operators like +=, or -=?

I've read this post, [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters), but it deals mainly with direct assignment in terms of `object.attr = value`. When thinking about it, I'm finding it difficult to be possible and I've never used setters so I'm not sure.

It is within the `Player.hit()` method where I'm attempting to achieve this where I'm subtracting and integer `reduced_points` from another integer `value` property:

```
self.hands[x].value -= reduced_points
```

NOTE: `Hand.value` is an `@property` due to that I need to dynamically add the values of each card in case a card is added to that hand.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, pip, suit, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pip = pip
        self.suit = suit
        if kwargs and 'face_card' in kwargs:
            self.face_card = kwargs['face_card']


class Hand:
    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.cards = cards # [Card(), Card(), Card()]
        self._value = sum(card.pip for card in cards)
    
    @property
    def soft(self):
        return any(
            hasattr(card, 'face_card') and
            card.face_card == "Ace" for card in self.cards
        )

    @property
    def value(self):
        return sum([card.pip for card in self.cards])

    @value.setter
    def set_value(self, value):
        new_value = self._value - value
        self._value = new_value
```

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Player"
        self.hands = []
        self.chips = 0
        self._bet = 0

    def hit(self, hand):
        if hand.soft:
            x, hand = list(filter(
                lambda h: h[1].soft, enumerate(self.hands)
            ))[0]
            total_aces = len(
                list(
                    filter(lambda c: hasattr(c, 'face_card') and
                    c.face_card == "Ace", self.hands[x].cards)
                )
            )
            reduced_points = 10 * (total_aces - 1)
            self.hands[x].value -= reduced_points
            if self.hands[x].value > 21:
                return self.hands[x], "BUST"
        if hand.value > 21:
            return hand , "BUST"
        return hand, "HIT"
```

Comment: Your setter makes no sense. Even if you fixed the name bug, you've implemented it in such a way that `hand.value = 5` *reduces* the value by 5 instead of setting the value to 5.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a property setter, it needs to have the same name as the getter.  So both the getter and setter needed to be `def value(...)`.  But yes, `hand.value -= 3` should do exactly what you expect it to.

Comment: The setter body makes no sense, so `hand.value -= 3` is going to do something completely different from reducing the value by 3.

Comment: I don't understand.  Python interprets `foo.value -= 3` as `foo.value = foo.value - 3`.  (Except that if `foo` is only evaluated once.).  Why is this unexpected?

Comment: That part is fine, but assigning to `foo.value` doesn't actually set the value to whatever you assigned, even with the setter name bug fixed. Look at what the setter is doing - it interprets `foo.value = whatever` as `foo._value -= whatever`.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the poster's code.  They asked whether `+=` or `-=` worked, and I responded in the affirmative.  I wasn't asked to--and didn't bother to--check if the code in question was doing the right thing.