# How to define toString method?

Tags: python

I have just almost finished my assignment and now the only thing I have left is to define the tostring method shown here.

```
import math

class RegularPolygon:
  def __init__(self, n = 1, l = 1):
    self.__n = n
    self.__l = l

  def set_n(self, n):
    self.__n = n

  def get_n(self):
    return self.__n

  def addSides(self, x):
    self.__n = self.__n + x

  def setLength(self, l ):
    self.__l = l

  def getLength(self):
    return self.__l 

  def setPerimeter(self):
    return (self.__n * self.__l )

  def getArea(self):
    return (self.__l ** 2 / 4 * math.tan(math.radians(180/self.__n)))

  def toString(self):
    return
x = 3
demo_object = RegularPolygon (3, 1)
print(demo_object.get_n() , demo_object.getLength())
demo_object.addSides(x)
print(demo_object.get_n(), demo_object.getLength())
print(demo_object.getArea())
print(demo_object.setPerimeter())
```

Basically the tostring on what it does is return a string that has the values of the internal variables included in it. I also need help on the getArea portion too.
Assignment instructions

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Please type in your requirements as text so they can be easily read.

Comment: Currently `toString` returns `None`. Have you attempted to implement anything there? What happened?

Comment: You are writing what I like to call "Pava", code that is written like Java with just enough Python syntax to be executed.

Comment: Yeah I just don't know what to return which in the assignment it says to return the internal variables included in it. So what would I put in it and then I'll do the rest of the assignment so I can turn it in since my teacher has been absent.

Comment: Using `toString()` would be very strange when you can use `__repr__` and  `__str__`

Comment: Do you need to return something like "RegularPolygon(3, 1)"? If so you should return `f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.__n}, {self.__l})'`

Comment: Where would I put that, I feel like those methods would be easier.

Comment: How would I correct the area formula?

Answer (score 2):

The assignment says

> ... printing a string representation of a RegularPolygon object.

So I would expect you get to choose a suitable "representation". You could go for something like this:

```py
return f'{self.__n+2} sided regular polygon of side length {self.__l}'
```

or as suggested by @Roy Cohen

```py
return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.__n}, {self.__l})'
```

*However*, as @Klaus D. wrote in the comments, Python *is not* Java, and as such has its own standards and magic methods to use instead.

I would recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/9063935) for an explanation between the differences between the two built-in string representation magic-methods: `__repr__` and `__str__`. By implementing these methods, they will automatically be called whenever using `print()` or something similar, instead of you calling `.toString()` every time.

Now to address the getters and setters. Typically in Python you avoid these and prefer using properties instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627002/9063935) for more information, but to summarise you either directly use an objects properties, or use the `@property` decorator to turn a method *into* a property.

**Edit**

Your area formula is likely an error with order-of-operations. Make sure you are explicit with which operation you're performing first:

```py
return self.__l ** 2 / (4 * math.tan(math.radians(180/self.__n)) )
```

This may be correct :)

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't need to use `property` in this case, just use the fields themselves. But you need to know that `property` exists in case you'd like to ever change the implementation of your class.