# Instance attribute getters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried writing a custom getter for a class attribute. But I am unable of finding the right syntax in Python. I tried what is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters) question but using the `@property` decorator does not seem to work or I am calling it incorrectly.

Class:

```
class Comment:
  def __init__(self):
    self.productRecommender = None

  @property
  def productRecommender(self):
    return self.productRecommender if self.productRecommender is not None else 'Onbekend'
```

Setting the attribute in the code (uses Selenium, comment is an instance of Comment()), should stay `None` if class is not found:

```
try:
  comment.recommender = comment.find_element_by_class_name('recommend').text
except NoSuchElementException:
  pass
```

Trying to access the value

```
comment.productRecommender
```

Comment: As in the linked question, all references to the actual underlying attribute should be prefixed: `self._productRecommender`

Comment: @Tomerikoo sorry for the indentation. Going to fix that (it's a copy/paste thing). Do you mean comment.productRecommender comment.self.productRecommender?

Comment: You cannot have the name of the property the same as the instance attribute name.
Change you instance attribute name to `_productRecommmender`, as mentioned by @Tomerikoo

Comment: I meant inside the class itself. Wherever you have `self.productRecommender` it should be `self._productRecommender`

Comment: @Tomerikoo, thanks. I finally got the issue looking at all the comments here and the posted example code. Need to get more used to OO in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be self._productRecommender and not self.productRecommender

```
class Comment():
    def __init__(self):
        self._productRecommender = None

    @property
    def productRecommender(self):
        print("getter called")
        return self._productRecommender if self._productRecommender is not None else 'Onbekend'

c = Comment()
foo = c.productRecommender
```

Comment: Some explanations make an answer much more valuable than code-only...