# Getter or setter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class ComplexNum:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def real(self):
        return self.x
    def imag(self):
        return self.y
    def get_r(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.y*self.y + self.x*self.x)
    def sqrt(self):
        complexA = cmath.sqrt(complex(self.x, self.y))
        A = ComplexT(complexA.real, complexA.imag)
        return A
    def sub(self, complexNum):
        a = complex(self.x,self.y)
        b = complex(complexNum.x, complexNum.y)
        c = a - b
        return ComplexT(c.real, c.imag)
```

I am a bit confused about the concept of getters and setters at the moment, What are the methods considered as? getters or setters or something else?

Comment: Don't write getters and setters in Python. But these are all getters

Comment: Also, don't write your own class for `complex` in Python.

Comment: Are you looking for [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 3):

You only have getters and instance methods here. Nothing is updating `self.? = ?` outside the constructor

That being said, if you are just doing `return self.?`, then it's not really necessary as you can access `complex_num_instance.?` directly without any function calls

Answer (score 2):

the methods shown in your code above would be 'getters' as they 'get' some sort of value once they are ran. Notice how they all return something.

IE:
number = complexnum.real()

the 'real' method would return self.x and store it in the 'number' variable. the number variable GOT a value from the real method. One convention that is commonly used is to name these methods with the prefix of 'get'. So this method would become 'get_real(self)'

A setter does kind of the opposite. A setter will 'set' a value.

IE:
If we wanted to SET the value of self.x you could have a method like this.
complexnum.set_x(3). This would set x's value to 3.

Here is your code retyped using these ideas:

```
# Code 
class ComplexNum:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def get_real(self):
        return self.x
    def get_imag(self):
        return self.y
    def get_r(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.y*self.y + self.x*self.x)
    def get_sqrt(self):
        complexA = cmath.sqrt(complex(self.x, self.y))
        A = ComplexT(complexA.real, complexA.imag)
        return A

    # Adding a setter
    def set_x(self, value):
        self.x = value
```

Comment: is the method sub a setter?

Comment: @killderich111 yes because it only returns some value and doesn't set any attributes. A setter is when you have something like `self.attribute = ...`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Wait, so it is a setter?

Comment: @killderich111 Sorry, a typo. I meant that. "No, it is a getter, because ...". Sorry