# Would the class look like that for the object test if I change the value test.i?

Tags: python, class, oop

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = "Test"
        self.o = f"{self.i} Test"
    

test = Test()
print(test.o)
test.i = "Hello"
```

If I change the value of the attribute `test.i`, wouldn't the class look like that (just for the object test)?

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = "Test"
        self.o = f"{self.i} Test"
        self.i = "Hello"
```

Comment: What did `print(test.i)` show you?

Comment: It showed me 'Test Test'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well:

by doing `test.i = "Hello"`, your are modifying its attribute `i` but your are not "modifying the class" nor its code. Your are simply changing the value of a variable that happens to be an object attribute.

So, the class "does not look like that" because it does not mean anything.

Moreover, when you change `test.i` after instantiating the class like you did, the value of `test.o` will **not** be changed.

See [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters) : you can use `@property` to change `test.o` when `test.i` is modified.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = "Test"

    @property
    def o(self):
        return f"{self.i} Test"
    

test = Test()
print(test.o)  # 'Test Test'
test.i = "Hello"
print(test.o) # 'Hello Test'
```

---

Keep in mind that Python only does what YOU tell it to do. If you tell it to change the value of `test.i`, `test.i` will have the new value, but python will not modify `test.o` unless you tell it to do so.

With the way you defined your class, when you create a new object by doing `test = Test()`, Python initializes it with the value you put in `__init__()`.

Then, when you change `test.i` by doing `test.i = "Hello"`, you only change this value and not the other properties of the class.

Think about it this way : if I have an object and I modify one of its attributes, i do not want the other to be modified unless I tell Python to do so... This would be an unwanted side effect.

The `@property` decorator allow you to define a function and then use it as a normal attribute. In this example, `test.o` is re-computed each time you ask for it with the value of `test.i`.

Side note : those are terrible variable names...

Comment: Yeah, because the value of test.o wont change, I wanted to ask, if i overwrite the variable test.i or just change the value. If i overwrite the value, test.o wouldnt change.

Comment: you can change your class so that it changes when you change `test.i`. see my updated answer

Comment: Yeah but I still dont understand, why If i change the value of test.i to "hello" test.o doesnt change. Idk if im dumb but thats why I ask, that If i change the value of test.i, does it overwrite the test.i or just change the value. For Example: test.i = "Test" will change to test.i = "Hello" or test.i = "Test" test.i = "Hello" In the second example im overwriting test.i

Comment: please edit your question and try to be a bit clearer :) (punctuation could be useful, especially in your last comment)

Comment: Ok, im tryng to be a bit clearer. My question is, if i change the value of the variable test.i, like in the example above, why does the value of test.o not change? And I think its since im overwriting the variable test.i after setting the value of test.o, so test.i changes, but test.o dont.

Comment: And if i use a second function, where I return that f string, then Im going to use the overwritten value of test.i

Comment: See my updated answer. Please also update your question with the content of your comments (questions should not be in comments but rather in the question body)

Comment: Yeah Ive seen it, thats why I asked that question. Im a bit confused rn :(

Answer (score 1):

By changing the value of `test.i` to `Hello` will not change the value of `i` of the  `class` .

`test` is an **object** of **class** `Test` and you are only changing the `i` value of `test` object **only**.

You need to know the difference between a Class and an Object.

> Please go through [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/)