# Constructing dataclasses with properties while using explicit keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, python-dataclasses

I would like to use a *dataclass* with an invariant that should not change during the lifetime of such instantiated objects. To indicate that the instance variables of these objects are *private*, their names are prefixed with an underscore. These instance variables can easily be accessed with the use of *properties*, as demonstrated with the [example code](https://godbolt.org/z/ceeP4zPM4) below:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C():
  _x: int = 3

  @property
  def x(self) -> int:
    return self._x

  def p(self) -> None:
    print(self._x)
```

The problem arises when I want to call the constructor of this class with explicit keyword arguments. To do so, I now have to provide the names of the instance variables with an underscore as well. This seems really counterintuitive, since the *private* variables are now accessed from outside of the class.

```
a = C()      # sets 'a.x' to 3
a.p()        # prints 3

b = C(5)     # sets 'b.x' to 5
b.p()        # prints 5

c = C(_x=7)  # sets 'c.x' to 7
c = C(x=7)   # error: unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

One way to solve this problem, is to simply provide an *explicit* constructor with matching arguments:

```
def __init__(self, x: int = 3) -> None:
  self._x = x
```

However, this also seems to be dreadfully counterintuitive as this approach contradicts the whole notion of a *dataclass*. Is there a way to use a *dataclass* in combination with *properties* that allows me to use explicit keyword arguments when constructing such objects without having to *access/acknowledge* instance variables intended to be *private*?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters) Especially the part about property setters.

Comment: @matszwecja Unfortunately not, as this problem is specific to utilizing *properties* with *dataclasses*.

Answer (score 1):

The dataclass is essentially a handful of methods that you can attach to your class. These methods provide reusable logic that dataclass developers thought applies to certain use cases. Setting private fields via `__init__` arguments is not among these use cases, so what you want is not supported by the `dataclass` module.

Luckily, it appears someone else has written a different module that does cover this use case: https://pypi.org/project/dataclass-property/

You could also look at some alternative frameworks, such as pydantic, to see if they meet your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

Would the "frozen" argument of the "dataclass" decorator fulfill your needs?

"
frozen: If true (the default is False), assigning to fields will generate an exception. This emulates read-only frozen instances. If **setattr**() or **delattr**() is defined in the class, then TypeError is raised. See the discussion below.
"

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html