# What's the proper way to set a google.protobuf.Int32Value in python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protobuf-python

I'm using [Google's Int32Value protobuf](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/wrappers_pb2.html) in python. I'm wondering what the proper way to set the value is. If we do it during initialization, then we can do

```
my_int_32_value = Int32Value(value=123)
```

If we try to set it after initialization, then is this the proper way?

```py
from google.protobuf.wrappers_pb2 import Int32Value

my_int_32_value = Int32Value()
my_int_32_value.value = 123
```

It seems to work, but also feels wrong to directly access the attribute like that, not via a setter.

EDIT:
For instance, to set a [Timestamp](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb2.html#google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2.Timestamp.FromDatetime) after it has been created, you can invoke the [FromDateTime function](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb2.html#google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2.Timestamp.FromDatetime), or some version of `MergeFrom` or `CopyFrom`

Comment: What does the documentation say about it? Why do you suppose that this is not "a setter"? What do you expect "setters" to look like in Python? Why?

Comment: the docs don't say anything about using the actual class. I suppose I forgot to add that in the past, I have used `MergeFrom` and `CopyFrom` syntax; certain WellKnownTypes have specific constructor functions; e.g. 
https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb2.html#google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2.Timestamp.FromDatetime

Comment: That seems like a perfectly ordinary way to change the value of an object that has a value.  If they wanted to protect, they'd use property setters.

Comment: Alright, thank you. It may have been a question arising from python inexperience; I suppose the pythonic way is to not use a setter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters