# Adding a Prepend Method to a Linked List Class

Tags: python, linked-list

I am currently working on a class project involving linked lists and python. Currently, I am trying to create a prepend function for said linked list. My current code is throwing a recursion error. Here is my code:

Node definition:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.previous = None
        # introduce a 'next' node for doubly linked list
        self.next = None

    def get(self):
        return self.data

    def getPrev(self):
        return self.previous

    def setPrev(self, previous):
        self.previous = previous

    def set(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setNext(self, next):
        self.next = next

    node = property(get, set)
    prev = property(getPrev, setPrev)
    next = property(getNext, setNext)
```

Here is the List function w/ append and broken prepend function:

```
class SList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tail = None
        # introduce 'head' node for double link
        self.head = None

    # appends to tail of list
    def Append(self, data):
        pdata = Node()
        pdata.node = data
        if self.tail is None:
            self.tail = pdata
        else:
            pdata.prev = self.tail
            self.tail = pdata

    # prepends to head of list
    def Prepend(self, data):
        pdata = Node()
        pdata.note = data
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = pdata
            pdata.step = self
        else:
            previous = self.head
            previous.step = pdata
            pdata.head = previous
            pdata.step = self
            self.head = pdata
```

The recursion error occurs at line 29 which is the setNext function:

```
def setNext(self, next)
    self.next = next
```

Comment: What is your question? Just guessing, you'd probably best make a drawing of the existing list and the one with the new element added to find which references to change and how.

Comment: Please add the traceback to your question showing the exact error. Saying "line 29" is almost meaningless when there are no line numbers shown.

Comment: This code has many issues. There are attributes accessed on a `Node` instance that are not defined in the constructor: `.node`, `.note`, `.step`, `.head`, `.prev`... Yet the attributes that **should** be accessed, like `.previous` and `.next` are not accessed nor in `Append`, nor in `Prepend`... Note also how your `Append` has fewer lines of code than `Prepend`, yet they should have the same amount of work to do...  And this is just scratching the surface of the problems. Did you run a debugging session at all?

Comment: `Node` is *wildly* overengineered. `__init__` is the only necessary method; all the others can be replaced by directly access to the attributes.

Comment: The problem is that your `next` property recursively references itself; there is no separate instance attribute named `next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- The setters and getters are overkill. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943813/5459839)... it is more pythonic to just use the attributes directly for simple classes. When your code works, it could be a final step to define *properties*, but it shouldn't be there when you are still having problems.
- Your code accesses several attributes that are not defined on `Node`, such as `head`, and `note`.
- When the list is empty, and a node is added, *both* the `head` and `tail` attributes must be set, not just one of them.
- Don't use PascalCase for methods, but camelCase. So `append`, not `Append`.µ
- Allow the `Node` constructor to get data as an argument.

Here is an implementation:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):  # Use argument
        self.data = data
        self.previous = None
        self.next = None

class SList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tail = None
        self.head = None

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node(data)  # use argument
        node.previous = self.tail
        if self.head is None:  # list is empty
            self.head = node  #  need to set head too!
        else:
            self.tail.next = node  #  need to link both directions
        self.tail = node

    def prepend(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        node.next = self.head
        if self.head is None:
            self.tail = node
        else:
            self.head.previous = node
        self.head = node
```

As in comments you indicate you don't get any output, here is some code that tests the above:

```
lst = SList()
lst.append(3)
lst.append(4)
lst.prepend(2)
lst.prepend(1)

node = lst.head
while node:
    print(node.data, end=" ")
    node = node.next
```

The output is:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your solution helped fix the recursion issue. However when I try to run the prepend/append code (after creating a list), it doesn't actually save anything. Instead of numbers it outputs None.

Comment: These methods are not supposed to return anything. They mutate the list. You need more code to actually output something from that list.

Comment: Anyway, I added a section to my answer showing you how you can get output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It turns out I just wrote my output function incorrectly haha!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the infinite recursion, use a different attribute name (e.g. `_next`) to store the value, like this:

```
def setNext(self, next);
    self._next = next
```