# Unintuitive syntax for fields/properties

Tags: python, properties, field

Today at work I had a session where I explained properties in Python to data science colleagues who were not very familiar with OOP in Python. Among the questions I received, there was the simple issue of why in Python the setter/getter situation is a bit unintuitive.

For example, if you have field in a class it is an expected behaviour that a method prefixed with `@property` will return a value of said field:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self._a = a
        
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
```

And then:

```
f = Bar(2)
print(f.a) # Out: 2
```

But what if you have a dedicated getter, like you would in other languages like Java or C#, it is sensible when you are trying to **get** a value of an attribute:

```
class Baz:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self._a = a
        
    @property
    def a(self):
        return None
    
    @a.getter
    def a(self):
        return self._a
```

And if we do:

```
bb = Baz(2)
print(bb.a)  # Out: 2
```

Here it returns 2 despite the fact that the field prefixed with `@property` supposedly returns `None`.

Obviously, for people *in the know* the fact that `@property` returns a value and the fact than *getter* is redundant in Python syntax is hardly an issue. And of course, the following doesn't work:

```
class Booz:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a
        
    @a.getter
    def a(self):
        return self.a

bbb = Booz(2) # Out: NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Is there a particular reason why fields in Python have to be defined in this unintuitive fashion, i.e. you would *expect* to get the value of a field from a *getter* and you would *expect* to set a value of a field with a setter. What is the inherent necessity for `@propery`?

Why is the following (Java-like) syntax not possible in Python:

```
class Booz:
    a: int 
        
    @a.getter
    def a(self):
        if isinstance(a, int):
            return self.a
```

Comment: Related: [What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: Only `@property` is needed to make a getter, so I don't see why the rant about `@a.getter`.

Comment: The short answer is, because it was shoehorned into Python (in v2.2). This was the way for Python to get accessors without radically changing the parser. `@property` wraps the function and creates the accessor. The accessor (since v2.6) has ways to modify the accessor (more precisely, replace the accessor with a new, updated one). `@a.setter` redefines the setter. `@a.deleter` redefines the deleter. And `@a.getter` redefines the getter; nothing sinister about it. Normally you don't need to redefine the getter, so `@a.getter` is almost never used.

Comment: @gre_gor, but the only thing `@property` does in the standard synstax is return the value of a field. In that case the naming is confusing. Why not just call it `@getter`?

Comment: Confusing with what?

Comment: @gre_gor, `@property` doesn't necessarily say that it is a way to *get* a value like a *getter* does. If you call a `getter` it is expected that you would *get* a value in return. Does `@property` intuitively say the same? No, it doesn't.

Comment: Because property is an object which gives an instance the ability to execute certain functions without the need for parentheses, imitating simple attributes. `bar.a` is normally a value, and `bar.a = 3` would normally replace the value with `3`. If `bar.a` is a property, `bar.a` invokes the getter function instead (whereas you would have to write `bar.a()` otherwise), `bar.a = 3` invokes the setter function, and `del bar.a` the deleter. This dispatching is done by the property. `@property` by default only defines the getter, but the property object itself is responsible for all three.

Comment: @Amadan, yes but why the `@property` decorator by default acts as a getter when you have a dedicated `getter` included in the syntax?

Comment: Because of the way `property` was defined: `property(fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None)`. Remember, this was the original way to use it, before decorators: a property object defines all three accessor methods. Now, using a function as a decorator (added later) will take the decorated function and give it as the first parameter: so `@property; def a...` is equivalent to `def a...; a = property(a)`. Take a look again at what the first argument of `property` is: a getter. It is a design that makes use of existing syntax to do a new thing, with minimal impact on existing code.

Comment: You could also do `a_prop = property(); @a_prop.getter; def a...` which might be more intuitive for you, but that produces an extra field (`a_prop`) that is not needed.  But this illustrates that `property` is a class with methods that update different accessor functions, and not just a confusing way to call a getter.

Comment: @Amadan, thanks. This makes sense even if on pure reading of the code (assuming the reader is not familiar with Python) it still doesn't make intuituve sense. But at least I have a better idea of how it came to be this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that properties were a band-aid added later, with some resistance.  It violates the "one way to do things" rule. The original implementation was like this:

```
class Baz:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self._a = a
        
    def set_a(self):
        return None
    
    def get_a(self):
        return self._a

    a = property(set_a, get_a)
```

This is somewhat sensible and orthogonal.  The decorator syntax was added a bit later.  The implementation is that the `@property` decorator creates the `a` property and populates either the getter or setter.  The `@a.getter` syntax modifies the property that had just been created by filling in the other field.

So, using the property is like saying

```
    a = property()
    a = a.setter(set_a)
    a = a.getter(get_a)
```

and I believe that's actually how the decorators are implemented.