# How to pass the value in one window class to one another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Hi guys I want the user to choose the motor speed before going into step. So, in the first class, I made the first window which asked for the motor speed and another one is the recording and predicting process. In the recording process, I want to collect the WAV file as future data and use the motor speed as a file name. But I cannot pass the self.RPM value from one class to another. This is some part of the code.

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    
    def setupUi(self, Form):

        #The rest of the code

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):

        #The rest of the code

    def start_click(self):
        print('Start button click')
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" color:#000000;\">Recording</span></p></body></html>"))
        app.processEvents()
        time.sleep(1)
        count = 0
        round = 0

        for i in range(3):
            round = i + 1
            text = "Round " + str(round) + "/3"
            self.label.setText(text)
            app.processEvents()
            print(text)

            #Recording
            now = datetime.now()
            day = now.strftime("%d")
            month = now.strftime("%m")
            year = now.strftime("%y")
            hour = now.strftime("%H")
            minute = now.strftime("%M")
            second = now.strftime("%S")
            print(day,"/",month,"/",year,hour,":",minute,":",second)
            
            CHUNK = 1024 #The number of frames in the buffer
            FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
            CHANNELS = 1 #Each frame will have 2 samples
            RATE = 44100 #The number of samples collected per second or we can called sample rate
            RECORD_SECONDS = 2 #Duration of recording
            WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = f"Data2/Test/{day}{month}{year}_{hour}{minute}{second}.wav" <--- I want to add RPM value here

            p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

            stream = p.open(format = FORMAT, channels = CHANNELS, rate = RATE, input = True, frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)
            
            print("* recording")
            
            frames = []

            for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
                data = stream.read(CHUNK) #read audio data from the stream
                frames.append(data)
            
            print("* done recording")
            self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" color:#000000;\">Done Recording</span></p></body></html>"))
            
            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()
            p.terminate()
            
            wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb') # 'rb' read only, 'wb' write only
            wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
            wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
            wf.setframerate(RATE)
            wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames)) #
            wf.close()

    #The rest of the code

class Ui_Form2(object):

    def openWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(422, 202)
        Form.setFixedSize(422, 202)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form, clicked = lambda: self.openWindow())
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 121, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form, clicked = lambda: self.openWindow())
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 121, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form, clicked = lambda: self.openWindow())
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 120, 121, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 281, 81))
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.label.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "1300 RPM"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.rpm_button_clicked(self.pushButton.text()))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "1500 RPM"))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.rpm_button_clicked(self.pushButton_2.text()))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "1800 RPM"))
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.rpm_button_clicked(self.pushButton_3.text()))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:18pt; font-weight:600;\">RPM Selection</span></p></body></html>"))
    
    def rpm_button_clicked(self, button_text):
        rpm_values = {'1300 RPM': 1300, '1500 RPM': 1500, '1800 RPM': 1800}
        self.RPM = rpm_values[button_text]
        print(self.RPM)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form2()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to use the value from one class on another or anyone got a better idea than this can suggest

Comment: I am not 100% as not an expert myself but have you tried adding return self.RPM to rpm_button_clicked? I think you may be able to use it that way (try UIForm2.RPM). On phone so please double check spelling

Comment: Object Oriented Programming ensure data encapsulation. Search somthing about `getter()` and `setter()` , e.g. [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943813/12621346)

Comment: Thx for all suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use signal/slots (a Qt mechanism for observer/observable), or do it the Python object way.

### Signal and slot

In the first case, you need to declare a signal in the class (**A**) where you select the motor speed, then in your other class (**B**) you `connect` the signal for your instance of A to a slot in your B instance.

When doing Qt graphical applications, I prefer to use toy examples to better understand how it works.

Here is what I mean :

```py
import sys
from typing import Optional

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class WindowA(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.setWindowTitle("A")

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Choose")
        central_widget.clicked.connect(self.on_button_Choose_pushed)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def on_button_Choose_pushed(self, checked: bool) -> None:
        print("'choose' button clicked")
        file_dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(parent=self)
        if file_dialog.exec():
            print("a file was selected")
            filenames = file_dialog.selectedFiles()
            print(filenames)
            assert len(filenames) == 1
            print("emitting the signal")
            self.file_selected.emit(filenames[0])
        else:
            print("no file selected")

    file_selected = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)


class WindowB(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window_a: WindowA):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.setWindowTitle("B")

        self.filename: Optional[str] = None

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Do something")
        central_widget.clicked.connect(self.on_button_Do_Something_pushed)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        window_a.file_selected.connect(self.on_file_selected)

    def on_button_Do_Something_pushed(self, checked: bool) -> None:
        print("'do something' button clicked")
        print("filename is :", repr(self.filename))
        # do something

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_file_selected(self, filename: str) -> None:
        print("'file selected' slot received a signal, filename =", repr(filename))
        self.filename = filename


def main() -> int:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window_a = WindowA()
    window_a.setVisible(True)
    window_b = WindowB(window_a)  # passing A to B
    window_b.setVisible(True)
    return app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

(the 2 windows may appear one on top of the other)

Click the button B "do something" button, then the A button "choose" and select a file, then click B again. You will get :

```py
'do something' button clicked
filename is : None
'choose' button clicked
a file was selected
['/home/stack_overflow/log.log']
emitting the signal
'file selected' slot received a signal, filename = '/home/stack_overflow/log.log'
'do something' button clicked
filename is : '/home/stack_overflow/log.log'
```

### Just objects

This is the over way around. You need your A to know of B, so that when a file is selected from A, it sets the variable for B.

```py
import sys
from typing import Optional

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class WindowA(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window_b: "WindowB"):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.setWindowTitle("A")

        self._window_b = window_b  # save it for later

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Choose")
        central_widget.clicked.connect(self.on_button_Choose_pushed)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def on_button_Choose_pushed(self, checked: bool) -> None:
        print("'choose' button clicked")
        file_dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(parent=self)
        if file_dialog.exec():
            print("a file was selected")
            filenames = file_dialog.selectedFiles()
            print(filenames)
            assert len(filenames) == 1
            print("setting the variable of B")
            self._window_b.filename = filenames[0]
        else:
            print("no file selected")


class WindowB(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.setWindowTitle("B")

        self.filename: Optional[str] = None

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Do something")
        central_widget.clicked.connect(self.on_button_Do_Something_pushed)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def on_button_Do_Something_pushed(self, checked: bool) -> None:
        print("'do something' button clicked")
        print("filename is :", self.filename)
        # do something


def main() -> int:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window_b = WindowB()
    window_b.setVisible(True)
    window_a = WindowA(window_b)  # passing B to A
    window_a.setVisible(True)
    return app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

This way, A sets the variable of B.

### Conclusion

If you understand these 2 techniques, you can change the structure. You can have a class containing the data, and the other being given a reference to the first class.
Or you could make the code that instantiate both of them (here is is the `main()` function) connect the signal from the first to the slot of the second.