# Having a mix of mutable/immutable "data container" python

Tags: python, immutability, dataclasses

I was wondering if there's a way to define within the same "data container" values of mutable/immutable/default values.

by "data container" I mean any things like `tuple`, `dict`, `class`, `Enum`,  `dataclass`

this example makes my point clear:

if I want to have `Page` with `first_page` `current_page` `last_page` as values.

if I would go with the `dataclass` method the implementation would be something like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True)
class Pages:
    first_page: int = 0 # need to be immutable
    current_page: int   # need to be initialized and mutable
    last_page: int      # need to be initialized and immutable
```

**can this be done? or is there a way to do it?**

Comment: You want to allow mutable parts of an `Enum`?

Comment: For a class, use getters and setters, see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters

Comment: @ScottHunter I know `Enum` works as `tuple`, and it violates the logic beyond `enums`, but I mentioned it because it falls in the same category. meaning that I'm storing *attributes* to specific *values*

Answer (score 0):

For a class, you can use getters and setters. For example, to have `first_page` be immutable, you can create a quasi-private property called `_first_page` (it's not actually private in Python), that you access via the (getter) property `first_page` attribute:

```py
class Pages:
    _first_page: int = 0
    
    @property
    def first_page(self):
        return self._first_page
```

With this, you can get `first_page`, but if you try setting `first_page` you will get an `AttributeError`:

```
p = Pages()
print(p.first_page)
0
p.first_page = 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 p.first_page = 2

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

You could have an equivalent `setter` attribute that explicitly returns a message that `first_page` is immuatble and does nothing, e.g.,:

```
class Pages:
    _first_page: int = 0
    
    @property
    def first_page(self):
        return self._first_page

    @first_page.setter
    def first_page(self, _):
        print("first_pass is immutable")
        pass
```

For values that you want to be mutable, you can just set the class attributes as you normally would, or (as above) use the `@property` and `@setter` decorated functions to set the equivalent quasi-private attributes.

Comment: I know I can use the usual class implementation to solve my problem.

*maybe I'm lazy* and looking for a easy and clear way as `enum` and `dataclass` **that using them clearly tells why I using them** unlike normal class.

plus, I know that `enum` and `tuple` are faster and to make.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `field` from `dataclasses`.

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)  # Making the dataclass frozen makes its fields immutable.
class Pages:
    _last_page: int = field(repr=False)  # Private field, and won't be shown in repr.
    _first_page: int = field(default=0, repr=False)
    current_page: int = field(default_factory=int, hash=False)  # Making it mutable by setting hash to False.

    @property
    def first_page(self) -> int:  # Property for the first_page to allow only reading.
        return self._first_page

    @property
    def last_page(self) -> int:  # Property for the last_page to allow only reading.
        return self._last_page
```

Testing

```
p = Pages(current_page=5, _last_page=10)
print(p.first_page)  # 0
print(p.current_page)  # 5
print(p.last_page)  # 10

# This will raise an exception: dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError
# p.first_page = 2
```

The `frozen=True` ensures that the attributes remain immutable unless otherwise specified.

Comment: but by assigning `frozen=True` this would make the whole `Pages` immutable, and trying to change `current_page` into another value would raise `dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Final` type annotation. Though it won't change the actual runtime behavior, at least your type checker will raise error when you try to overwrite the value.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Final

@dataclass(slots=True)
class Pages:
    current_page: int   # need to be initialized and mutable
    last_page: Final[int]      # need to be initialized and immutable
    first_page: Final[int] = 0 # need to be immutable
```